# Disable/enable an input with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-input, disabled-input

```
$input.disabled = true;
```

or

```
$input.disabled = "disabled";
```

Which is the standard way? And, conversely, how do you enable a disabled input?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove disabled attribute using JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626517/remove-disabled-attribute-using-jquery)

Comment: I found the [DependsOn](https://github.com/dstreet/dependsOn) plugin which you might find useful

Answer (score 4132, accepted):

### jQuery 1.6+

To change the `disabled` property you should use the [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop) function.

```
$("input").prop('disabled', true);
$("input").prop('disabled', false);
```

### jQuery 1.5 and below

The `.prop()` function doesn't exist, but [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) does similar:

Set the disabled attribute.

```
$("input").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

To enable again, the proper method is to use [`.removeAttr()`](//api.jquery.com/removeAttr)

```
$("input").removeAttr('disabled');
```

### In any version of jQuery

You can always rely on the actual DOM object and is probably a little faster than the other two options if you are only dealing with one element:

```
// assuming an event handler thus 'this'
this.disabled = true;
```

The advantage to using the `.prop()` or `.attr()` methods is that you can set the property for a bunch of selected items.

---

**Note:** In 1.6 there is a [`.removeProp()`](//api.jquery.com/removeProp) method that sounds a lot like `removeAttr()`, but it **SHOULD NOT BE USED** on native properties like `'disabled'`  Excerpt from the documentation:

> Note: Do not use this method to remove native properties such as checked, disabled, or selected. This will remove the property completely and, once removed, cannot be added again to element. Use .prop() to set these properties to false instead.

In fact, I doubt there are many legitimate uses for this method, boolean props are done in such a way that you should set them to false instead of "removing" them like their "attribute" counterparts in 1.5

Comment: As an aside, remember that, if you want to disable ALL form input controls - incl. checkboxes, radios, textareas, etc. - you have to select `':input'`, not just `'input'`. The latter selects only actual <input> elements.

Comment: @CornelMasson `input,textarea,select,button` is a little better to use than `:input` -- `:input` as a selector is quite inefficient because it has to select `*` then loop over each element and filter by tagname - if you pass the 4 tagname selectors directly it is MUCH faster.  Also, `:input` is not a standard CSS selector, so any performance gains that are possible from `querySelectorAll` are lost

Comment: Does this just prevent the user from accessing it, or does it actually remove it from the web request?

Comment: @bwheeler96 It does both. A disabled `input` element will not be submitted, and the user will be unable to change its value.

Comment: Also remember to use true/false booleans and not strings to enable/disable properties

Comment: Using the `.removeProp("disabled")` was causing the issue of "property getting removed completely and not getting added again" as pointed out by @ThomasDavidBaker, in case of some browsers like Chrome, whereas it was working fine on some like Firefox. We should really be careful here. Always use `.prop("disabled",false)` instead

Comment: Neither .prop or .attr are sufficient for disabling anchor elements; .prop won't even grey out the 'control' (.attr does, but the href is still active). You have to also add a click event handler that calls preventDefault().

Comment: Since IE8 and below don't support the `:disabled` pseudo-class, you have to use the `[disabled=disabled]` selector to style disabled objects - which means you should follow geekbuntu's answer below if you care about cross-browser support. Basically, despite the large number of upvotes, this answer is incorrect and `attr` / `removeAttr` is the way to go.

Comment: @JeffLowery You are right. I have to use them both to disable an anchor element.

Comment: var o=$("#elem");o.disabled=true; does not work here. It would be nice if it did, any thoughts?

Comment: the funniest part of this answer is the use of single quotes and double quotes in the same line of JavaScript

Comment: This ties in with slightly with the issue of toggling an input being enabled or disabled. If you use this in the inputs own .click event it will work to disable, but then the input element itself becomes unclickable after its disabled. Consider using this on a container for the input such as a div, span, or even an li if in a list style form.

Comment: what should be done for dynamically adding elements.?!

Comment: Not working for me > this.disabled = true

Answer (score 68):

Just for the sake of new conventions && making it adaptable going forward (unless things change drastically with ECMA6(????):

```
$(document).on('event_name', '#your_id', function() {
    $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

and

```
$(document).off('event_name', '#your_id', function() {
    $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');   
});
```

Comment: Jikes! Why `$(document).on('event_name', '#your_id', function() {...})` instead of `$('#your_id').on('event_name', function() {...})`.  As described in the [jQuery .on() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) the former uses delegation and listens to _all_ `event_name` events that bubble up to `document` and checks them for a matching `#your_id`. The latter listens specifically to `$('#your_id')` events only and that scales better.

Comment: The former works for elements inserted into the DOM at any point, the latter only for those extant at that moment.

Comment: @crazymykl Correct but you shouldn't add elements with an id already present on your page.

Answer (score 51):

```
// Disable #x
$( "#x" ).prop( "disabled", true );
// Enable #x
$( "#x" ).prop( "disabled", false );
```

Sometimes you need to disable/enable the form element like input or textarea. Jquery helps you to easily make this with setting disabled attribute to "disabled".
For e.g.:

```
//To disable 
$('.someElement').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

To enable disabled element you need to remove "disabled" attribute from this element or empty it's string. For e.g:

```
//To enable 
$('.someElement').removeAttr('disabled');

// OR you can set attr to "" 
$('.someElement').attr('disabled', '');
```

reference: http://garmoncheg.blogspot.fr/2011/07/how-to-disableenable-element-with.html

Answer (score 18):

```
$("input")[0].disabled = true;
```

or

```
$("input")[0].disabled = false;
```

Comment: Of course the question asked for jQuery and this is changing the state in plain JavaScript, but it works.

Comment: This changes the state in JavaScript, but it still uses a jQuery selector to get the first input.

Comment: But i don't think we are making encyclopedia of jquery here, if an answer works, it's good

Answer (score 17):

There are many ways using them you can enable/disable any element **:**

**Approach 1**

```
$("#txtName").attr("disabled", true);
```

**Approach 2**

```
$("#txtName").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

If you are using jQuery 1.7 or higher version then use prop(), instead of attr().

```
$("#txtName").prop("disabled", "disabled");
```

If you wish to enable any element then you just have to do opposite of what you did to make it disable. However jQuery provides another way to remove any attribute.

**Approach 1**

```
$("#txtName").attr("disabled", false);
```

**Approach 2**

```
$("#txtName").attr("disabled", "");
```

**Approach 3**

```
$("#txtName").removeAttr("disabled");
```

Again, if you are using jQuery 1.7 or higher version then use prop(), instead of attr(). That's is. This is how you enable or disable any element using jQuery.

Answer (score 13):

Use like this,

```
 $( "#id" ).prop( "disabled", true );

 $( "#id" ).prop( "disabled", false );
```

Answer (score 11):

If you just want to invert the current state (like a toggle button behaviour):

```
$("input").prop('disabled', ! $("input").prop('disabled') );
```

As noted in comments, the following will also toggle the prop:

```
$("input").prop('disabled', function(i, v) { return !v; });
```

Comment: thanks i have a same thing for the toggle it is;

$("input").prop('disabled', function(i, v) { return !v; });

Answer (score 9):

You can put this somewhere global in your code:

```
$.prototype.enable = function () {
    $.each(this, function (index, el) {
        $(el).removeAttr('disabled');
    });
}

$.prototype.disable = function () {
    $.each(this, function (index, el) {
        $(el).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
}
```

And then you can write stuff like:

```
$(".myInputs").enable();
$("#otherInput").disable();
```

Comment: While wrapping the functionality is handy, you should have used `prop` and *not* `attr` with the `disabled` property for it to work correctly (assuming jQuery 1.6 or above).

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie What is the downside of using `attr` ? I use the above code in some projects and as far as I remember it works ok

Comment: The obvious exceptions are controls with properties behind the scenes. The most famous one is the `checked` property of checkboxes. Using `attr` will not give the same result.

Answer (score 3):

Update for 2018:

Now there's no need for jQuery and it's been a while since `document.querySelector`  or `document.querySelectorAll` (for multiple elements) do almost exactly same job as $, plus more explicit ones `getElementById`, `getElementsByClassName`, `getElementsByTagName`

Disabling one field of "input-checkbox" class

```
document.querySelector('.input-checkbox').disabled = true;
```

or multiple elements

```
document.querySelectorAll('.input-checkbox').forEach(el => el.disabled = true);
```

Comment: the question specifically asks about jQuery...but equally your statement is correct, and worth knowing that jQuery doesn't _need_ to be used for this when there are multiple elements anymore.

Answer (score 3):

this works for me

```
$("#values:input").attr("disabled",true);
$("#values:input").attr("disabled",false);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the jQuery prop() method to disable or enable form element or control dynamically using jQuery. The prop() method require jQuery 1.6 and above.

**Example:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('form input[type="submit"]').prop("disabled", true);
            $(".agree").click(function(){
                if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
                    $('form input[type="submit"]').prop("disabled", false);
                }
                else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
                    $('form input[type="submit"]').prop("disabled", true);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Disable true for input type :**

> In case of a specific input type (*Ex. Text type input*)

```
$("input[type=text]").attr('disabled', true);
```

> For all type of input type

```
$("input").attr('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me isolate to an input name.     ```$("input[name=method]").prop('disabled', true);```

Answer (score 1):

Disable:

```
$('input').attr('readonly', true); // Disable it.
$('input').addClass('text-muted'); // Gray it out with bootstrap.
```

Enable:

```
$('input').attr('readonly', false); // Enable it.
$('input').removeClass('text-muted'); // Back to normal color with bootstrap.
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternate way to disable the input field is by using jQuery and css like this:

```
jQuery("#inputFieldId").css({"pointer-events":"none"})
```

and to enable the same input the code is as follows:

```
jQuery("#inputFieldId").css({"pointer-events":""})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>

Name: <input type="text" id="myText">



<button onclick="disable()">Disable Text field</button>
<button onclick="enable()">Enable Text field</button>

<script>
function disable() {
    document.getElementById("myText").disabled = true;
}
function enable() {
    document.getElementById("myText").disabled = false;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 0):

I used @gnarf answer and added it as function

```
   $.fn.disabled = function (isDisabled) {
     if (isDisabled) {
       this.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
     } else {
       this.removeAttr('disabled');
     }
   };
```

Then use like this

```
$('#myElement').disable(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

### 2018, without JQuery (ES6)

Disable all `input`:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('input')].map(e => e.disabled = true);
```

Disable `input` with `id="my-input"`

```
document.getElementById('my-input').disabled = true;
```

*The question is **with** JQuery, it's just FYI.*

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 4** (this is extension of [wild coder answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51651968/860099))

```js
txtName.disabled=1     // 0 for enable
```

```html
<input id="txtName">
```

Answer (score -1):

In jQuery Mobile:

#### For disable

```
$('#someselectElement').selectmenu().selectmenu('disable').selectmenu('refresh', true);
$('#someTextElement').textinput().textinput('disable');
```

#### For enable

```
$('#someselectElement').selectmenu().selectmenu('enable').selectmenu('refresh', true);
$('#someTextElement').textinput('enable');
```