# How to disable all <input > inside a form with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, forms

```
<form id="target">
....
</form>
```

Answer (score 326, accepted):

In older versions you could use [`attr`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/). As of jQuery 1.6 you should use [`prop`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead:

```
$("#target :input").prop("disabled", true);
```

To disable all form elements inside 'target'. See [`:input`](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/):

> Matches all input, textarea, select and button elements.

If you only want the `<input>` elements:

```
$("#target input").prop("disabled", true);
```

Comment: As of jQuery 1.6 you should use `$("#target :input").prop("disabled", true);`

Comment: Someone should edit the answer with the updated method -- this is just bad information at this point.

Comment: and in a submit() callback, using $(this), how to do that?

Comment: @OlivierPons `$(this).closest('form').find('input').prop('disabled', true);`.  Not sure if you can consolidate that better, I'm still rather noobish at jQuery.

Answer (score 44):

Above example is technically incorrect. Per latest jQuery, use the `prop()` method should be used for things like disabled. [See their API page.](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

To disable all form elements inside 'target', use the :input selector which matches all input, textarea, select and button elements.

```
$("#target :input").prop("disabled", true);
```

If you only want the  elements, use this.

```
$("#target input").prop("disabled", true);
```

Answer (score 18):

Also the more concise way is to use their selectors engine. 
So to disable all form elements in a div or form parent.

```
$myForm.find(':input:not(:disabled)').prop('disabled',true)
```

Answer (score 16):

you can add

```
 <fieldset class="fieldset">
```

and then you can call

```
 $('.fieldset').prop('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 12):

With this one line you can disable any input field in a form

```
$('form *').prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: this unnecessarily adds a disabled property to every element in the form.

Comment: @OsvaldoMaria yeah, that is because of the star (all) selector, you could add a .custom-class to all input elements you want to disable, then change the selector to $('form .custom-class').prop('disabled', true').

Answer (score 11):

To disable all form, as easy as write:

**jQuery 1.6+**

```
$("#form :input").prop("disabled", true);
```

**jQuery 1.5 and below**

```
$("#form :input").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
//HTML BUTTON
<button type="button" onclick="disableAll()">Disable</button>

//Jquery function
function disableAll() {
    //DISABLE ALL FIELDS THAT ARE NOT DISABLED
    $('form').find(':input:not(:disabled)').prop('disabled', true);

    //ENABLE ALL FIELDS THAT DISABLED
    //$('form').find(':input(:disabled)').prop('disabled', false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The definitive answer (covering changes to jQuery api at version 1.6) has been given by [Gnarf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414365/how-to-disable-enable-an-input-with-jquery?rq=1)

Comment: He asked to "disable all inputs inside a form", not just "disable all inputs".

Comment: @Bengala sure, but you're marking me harshly for being the first to point out the API had changed. At the time I posted this none of the other answers mentioned this point.

Comment: I understand, but I think you should include a correct answer with the respective credits, the link just show how to disable all inputs, which I insist, it doesn't answer at all the question.