# Hide and disable with jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a section of my page that I want to hide when the user clicks a certain radio button.  But in addition to hiding the area, I want disable all inputs in that area.  I also want to bring back the area when the user hits another button.

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: listen for the click event on the radio button, if it is checked, hide the div/span. else show . You should be able to do it yourself. check out the jQuery documentation. This is how you learn

Comment: After asking more than 80 questions on SO, you should know that without codes people cannot help you as it should.

Comment: I would start by reading http://api.jquery.com/hide/ and [How to disable all `<input >` inside a form with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416900/how-to-disable-all-input-inside-a-form-with-jquery)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try something like below:

```
$('#make_hide_button').on('click', function() {
  $('#target_area').hide().find('input, textarea').prop('disabled', true);
});

$('#make_show_button').on('click', function() {
  $('#target_area').show().find('input, textarea').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

As you have specified no current code you are working with I can only give you a few general guidelines.

Have a look at jQuery [**hide()**](http://api.jquery.com/hide/):

```
$("#myDivId").hide();
```

Check how to bind click events using [**on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$("#MyRadioButton").on("click", function(){
    $("#myDivId").hide();
});

$("#MyOtherButton").on("click", function(){
    $("#myDivId").show();
});
```

To disable/enable elements:

```
$("#MyElementId").prop("disabled", false);

$("#MyElementId").prop("disabled", true);
```

Again, this is something to get your started, ones you have some code you experience issues with, please feel free to post it and I'm sure we can manage to help you out.

Comment: +1 For the constructive guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

More code in your question would definitely have a strong relation to having code in answers.

That being said, a general approach is going to be making sure you know which area the input was in. Perhaps with `data-` attributes or a javascript array of ids, or maybe by classname.

Once the area is well defined, you can hide the radio button, and then iterate through the defined area disabling any elements which are of type input.

**EDIT**

Assumptions:

you want the entire form disabled if the radio button is clicked:

your radio button has an id of "radButt"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function GetParentForm(elem) {
    while (elem && elem.nodeName && elem.nodeName.toUpperCase() != "FORM") {
        elem = elem.parentNode;
    }
    return elem;
 }

 var changeState = 0;
 $("#radButt").click( function() {
   $(this).hide();
   var thisForm = GetParentForm( $(this)[0] );
   $(thisForm).find('input').prop('disabled', true);
 });
</script>
```