# Disabling dynamically created Text boxes

Tags: javascript

I'm creating text boxes and radio buttons dynamically and fields are fetched from database. For my task, I need to disable some text boxes by ticking of radio buttons using javascript. However radio buttons are visible always. For an example, If i click first radio button, it should disable 2nd and 3rd of text boxes , not radio button.

How could i achieve this using javascript?

Comment: Set the [disabled](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-50886781) property of the relevant input elements to true.

Comment: @RobG this is an answer post it in answer

Comment: You may refer this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648901/disable-textbox-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<input type='radio' name='r1' value="NE" />
<input type='radio' name='r1' value="NW" />
<input type='radio' name='r1' value="SE" />

<input type='textbox' id="txt1" name='txt1' value="NE"/>
<input type='textbox' id="txt2" name='txt2' value="NW"/>
<input type='textbox' id="txt3" name='txt3' value="SE"/>
```

JavaScript:

```
// First assign onclick handler to your radio buttons
// Note - this is just a demo. You should encapsulate 
// this loop in a page onload initialization method.
var radios = document.forms[0].elements["r1"];
for(var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
   radios[i].onclick = DisableTextBoxes;
}

// Disable textboxes based on respective radio click
function DisableTextBoxes(){    
  var textboxes = [
     document.getElementById("txt1"),
     document.getElementById("txt2"),
     document.getElementById("txt3")]

  for(var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
     if(radios[i].checked) {
        textboxes[i].disabled = false;
     } else {
        textboxes[i].disabled = true;
     }
  }
}
```

A more thorough explanation can be found [here](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1812-having-javascript-perform-an-action-when-a-radio-button-is-clicked/).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, you can use the `:text` or `input[type=text]` selectors to choose text boxes for manipulation.

For example, to disable the first text box that immediately follows a checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check1" id="check1" value="Yes">
<input type="text" id="txt1" name="txt1">

<script type="javascript">
$("#check1").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
        $(this).next(":text").attr('disabled','true');
    else
        $(this).next(":text").removeAttr('disabled');
});
</script>
```