# i have use this code.But cannot disable some text box.So,how can i disabled some text box?

Tags: jquery

```
$('#tab_logic tbody tr').each(function(i, element){
    var y=1;

    y++;

    $('#ProductId'+y).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#ProductName'+y).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#AvailableQuantity'+y).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#LastPurchaseCost'+y).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#MinimumLevelQuantity'+y).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [disable textbox using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648901/disable-textbox-using-jquery)

Comment: Syntax to disable seems correct, so my guess would be there's something wrong with the selector(s) you are using. Hard to tell with the few amount of info you are providing us.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know your problem, you have a table, and inside each row you put those textbox with same ID, that the reason, in HTML you all the ID is unique, so if you use $("#ID") will only choose first element.

try to use class. like .productId, so in each row will be $(this).find(".productId").prop("disabled", true).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to declare a global variable.

```
var y=0;
$('#tab_logic tbody tr').each(function(i, element){
    $('#ProductId'+y).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#ProductName'+y).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#AvailableQuantity'+y).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#LastPurchaseCost'+y).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#MinimumLevelQuantity'+y).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    y++;
});
```