# removeAttr() issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hands up - I can't figure it out what's wrong with it. Is that a bug or a wrong code ?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#rem_but").click(function(){

    var mail_name = $("#mail_rem").val();
    var dataString = 'mail_name='+ mail_name;


    if (mail_name.val() == "") {  $("#rem_but").attr("disabled",true); } 
    else {  $("#rem_but").removeAttr("disabled"); };
}); });
```

So when there's no input the button returns false correctly - when there's an input in the field - still the button returns false, hence the removeAttr() doesn't work - why ? Regards.

Comment: You should be getting JavaScript errors in the console.

Comment: rem_but is not a submit button right?  Rather its just a regular button?

Comment: @Kris - yes it's a 'button' type...<input type="text" maxlength="50" id="mail_rem" name="mail_rem" /><br/><br/>
<input type="button" id="rem_but" name="rem_but" value="submit"/>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using jQuery 1.6.x?

If so then you should try using the `.prop()` function.  See below:

[Disable/enable an input with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414365/how-to-disable-an-input-with-jquery)

Also, in your if statement no need to keep selecting `$("#rem_but")`.  Based on your code I would recommend `$(this)` instead -

```
$(this).prop('disabled', true);
```

This should work -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#rem_but").click(function(e) {

 e.preventDefault();

 var mail_name = $.trim($("#mail_rem").val());
 var dataString = 'mail_name='+ mail_name;

 if (mail_name === "") {  
    $(this).prop("disabled", true); }
 else {  
    $(this).prop("disabled", false); }
 });
});
```

Here is the working jsFiddle code -

http://jsfiddle.net/4rPc5/

Updated code -

http://jsfiddle.net/4rPc5/2/

Comment: Upgrade?  I cannot answer that for you because I do not understand the implications or your application.

Comment: Is this a new app or a small app?  Then I would answer yes.  Do you have unit tests to double-check?

Comment: It's a small poput window with one field for a mail address input ( to reset it ) a very simple code...When the field is empty the button works fine returning false , when not - the button still returns false and removeAtrr() or prop() doesn't work for some reason...( I'm not sure if I used prop() method correctly though - I'm using 1.6.4 version now )

Comment: I just updated the example code to include another button to enable the first button.  And it also uses the keyup() event so you do not need an extra button.

Comment: thanks a lot - I saw the code. works but is this a workaround ? I just need one simple button that submits ( enables ) when there's anything in the field and simpy doesn't when there's nothing....It looks like a bug to me..( I don't want to implement 3 buttons - although I appreciate your solution of course ! )

Comment: "return" out of the function when the value is an empty string to not continue to the ajax call.

Comment: Thank you Kris ! Indeed - this one is working http://jsfiddle.net/4rPc5/5/ Regards..

Answer (score 5):

try `(mail_name.val() == "")` change to `(mail_name == "")`

Comment: Also, if you use jQuery version 1.6+, use `prop("disabled")` instead of `attr("disabled")`: http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/12/jquery-1-6-1-released/

Comment: One more thing: if your button is disabled, click will not work

Comment: you can always have another element that enables it :)

Comment: I've been trying using prop() like this: $('#rem_but').prop('disabled',false) - still doesn't work...

Comment: @simoncereska Hi - so what do you suggest then ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/simoncereska/TKzA8/ take a look, maybe this is what you are looking for

Comment: @simoncereska - nope...interesting - the code is so simple. To sum up - the '===' operator makes the button submit when the field is empty...so I need to use '=='..

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to set the disabled attribute to 'false'?

```
if (mail_name.val() == "") {  $("#rem_but").attr("disabled",true); } 
else {  $("#rem_but").attr("disabled",false); };
}
```

Or set it to an empty string

```
if (mail_name.val() == "") {  $("#rem_but").attr("disabled",true); } 
else {  $("#rem_but").attr("disabled",""); };
}
```

Comment: Hi..I've been trying to do so as well - to no avail...Now I upgraded to 1.6.4...so I don't think you can use attr()..P.S. Your method didn't work in the previous version, I tried it..