# jQuery to disable button not work

Tags: jquery, html

I used to bind event to my button like :

```
$("input[name=add]").live("click",function(){...});
```

But I got another function to make them "enable" and "disabled" like :

```
RefreshBox() {

    $("input[name=add]").each(function(){
        if(...)
            $(this).attr("disabled","disabled");
        else
            $(this).attr("disabled","");
    })

}
```

But in fact that it doesn't work as I expected. Buttons are still can be click and the event still works smoothly.

PS:
jQuery 1.4.1
Browser: IE8 , after button disabled still can work.
Browser: Chrome, disabled button success.

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this problem. See http://jsfiddle.net/liho1eye/yfA8d/ for sample code. I suspect you either not using correct selector or your disabling code is not being called.

Comment: @BookOfZeu It's only a simulated predicate showing my status. Buttons can disabled and enabled, but event still can be triggered when disabled.

Comment: i need help on this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20225962/jquery-form-disable-submit-button-until-required-field-entered

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You'll want to use the [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) function instead of `attr`:

```
$(this).prop("disabled", true);
```

and

```
$(this).prop("disabled", false);
```

**EDIT**

OP was using jQuery pre 1.6.1, which was why `attr` for `disabled` wasn't working quite right (for older IE).  While `prop` is preferred for `disabled`, post 1.6.1 `attr` should (and does) work as well.

Comment: Isn't disabled also an attribute? E.g. `disabled="disabled"`

Comment: If I am reading the question correctly, his issue is that he cannot disable the button, not reenable.

Comment: @PeeHaa - I'm not an expert here, but the jQuery docs recommend using prop instead of attr for disabled.  That OP's problem is with IE8 makes me think this might be one of the edge cases that prop is supposed to take care of

Comment: @liho1eye - this SO Q seems to imply otherwise http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677886/ie7-ie8-interaction-with-jquery-removeattrdisabled-not-applying-css

Comment: And as this link implies, it *can* make a difference if OP is using jQuery < 1.6.1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169826/propchecked-false-or-removeattrchecked

Comment: @Ericpoon - after updating to 1.7, did using prop like in my answer solve your problem?

Comment: @Ericpoon - sorry, I misread your comment.  No, you don't have to update to 1.7.  Just change your code to use prop like above, and see if that fixes it

Comment: @AdamRackis I only download 1.6.1. Problem is solved. I can use $.attr() to disable buttons and they're never trigger the events bind with $.live(). Thanks.

Comment: @Ericpoon - 1.6.1 put a fix in to make removeAttr behave as it should, which is why it now works, but consider switching your code to use `prop`.  That's the recommended way to handle attributes with boolean values—like checked and disabled

Comment: @liho1eye - I edited my answer to describe why `attr` was not working for OP, and why `prop` would—as would, as you said, `attr` with a more recent jQuery version.

Comment: @AdamRackis I retract my -1 then.

Comment: @AdamRackis Yes, prop() can work very well. But attr("disabled") also can work after 1.6.1. ^_^

Answer (score 5):

Try `$("input[type=submit]").removeAttr("disabled");` to enable the button.

Comment: Not the issue the OP is describing.

Comment: I mean the button still can be click after I disabled it with code $.attr("disabled","disabled");

Answer (score 3):

You can set the 'disabled' attribute to false by using:

```
$("input[name='add']").attr("disabled","disabled");
```