# Disabling button in javascript not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a requirement to disable a button when no value is found for a certain object. This code works in FF and the button is greyed out. It doesn't work in IE however.

Here is my code:

```
if(c4Obj.getValueByName("Combined_Order",1)=="")  
    $("#StockPlates_btn").attr('disabled', true)
else 
    $("#StockPlates_btn").attr('disabled', false);
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: Try `.prop` instead of `.attr`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery to disable button not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707423/jquery-to-disable-button-not-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
if(c4Obj.getValueByName("Combined_Order",1)=="")  
    $("#StockPlates_btn").attr('disabled', 'disabled')
else 
    $("#StockPlates_btn").removeAttr('disabled');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#StockPlates_btn").click(function(){
    $("#StockPlates_btn").preventDefault();
 })
```

Try this. This will prevent click event when you click on it.

Answer (score 0):

As Dave mentioned it should be disabled equals disabled for an option to be disabled in HTML.

The disabled attribute is not supported in IE, prior version 8.

Reference:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_disabled.asp

Answer (score 0):

may be you are using jQuery pre 1.6.1 version, which was why attr for disabled wasn't working quite right (for older IE).. by busing prop you can achive the task easily
try like this

```
if(c4Obj.getValueByName("Combined_Order",1)=="")  
    $("#StockPlates_btn").prop('disabled', true)
else 
    $("#StockPlates_btn").prop('disabled', false);
```