# Button disable and enable not working in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a Jquery for click a button to add items to list.here I need to disable the button after click on it and after success it will be enable.here is my Code

```
$(".addtowishlist").live("click", function (e) {
        var t = $(this);
        $('<img src="/images/loading.gif" alt="loading" id="ajax-loader-wish"/>').insertAfter(t);
        $("#simplemodal-overlay").unbind("click");
        var n = t.parent().find("select[name='code']").val();

        var i = t.parent().find("input:hidden[name='account']").val();
        var s = t.parent().find("input:hidden[name='itemname']").val();
        var o = t.parent().find("input:hidden[name='itemnumber']").val();
        var u = (new URI).addQuery("code", n).addQuery("qty", 0).addQuery("addtowishlist", true).addQuery("account", i).addQuery("itemname", s).addQuery("itemnumber", o);
        $.ajax({
            url: u,
            type: "GET",
            success: function (e) {
                t.closest(".innerwishlist").hide();
                $(".wishlistThankYou").show()
            }
        });
        return false
    });
```

I tried

```
$(".addtowishlist").attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
and code for enable 

 $(".addtowishlist").attr('disabled', '');
```

its works and disable the button but it doesn't enable the button after success.
anybody help ?

Comment: Unrelated: `.live()` is deprecated, and removed in jQuery 1.9. Convert to `.on()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery to disable button not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707423/jquery-to-disable-button-not-work)

Comment: +1 Agree with @Barmar that `.live()` is no longer supported.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is recommended to use `.prop` instead:

```
$(".addtowishlist").prop('disabled', true); 
$(".addtowishlist").prop('disabled', false);
```

Or if you use old version of jQuery, use `$(".addtowishlist").removeAttr("disabled");` to remove the attribute.

Comment: @xdazz..why `prop` instead of `attr`?

Comment: @OlracVaizard According to the W3C forms specification, the disabled attribute is a boolean attribute.

Answer (score 4):

```
$(".addtowishlist").attr('disabled', true); 
and code for enable 

 $(".addtowishlist").attr('disabled', false);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(".addtowishlist").removeAttr("disabled");
```

Answer (score 0):

If the button is itself a jQuery styled button (with .button()) you will need to refresh the state of the button so that the correct classes are added / removed.

```
$( ".selector" ).button( "refresh" );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **jQuery version 1.6+**, then

```
$(".addtowishlist").prop( "disabled", true);
```

is recommended to disable the field. And for enabling use

```
$(".addtowishlist").prop( "disabled", false );
```

For **older jQuery versions** use below for disabling

```
$(".addtowishlist").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

and below one for enabling.

```
$(".addtowishlist").removeAttr('disabled');
```