# How to disable/enable input field on click with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to properly enable/disable input field on click with jQuery?

I was experimenting with:

```
$("#FullName").removeAttr('disabled');
```

which removes `disabled="disabled"` from this input field:

```
<input id="FullName" style="width: 299px" value="Marko" disabled="disabled" />
```

But how to add it again with click on another button or how to disable input field on click?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414365/how-to-disable-an-input-with-jquery check here

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For jQuery version 1.6+ use `prop`:

```
$('#elementId').click(function(){
        $('#FullName').prop('disabled', true\false);
});
```

For older versions of jQuery use `attr`:

```
$('#elementId').click(function(){
        $('#FullName').attr('disabled', 'disabled'\'');
});
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$("#FullName").prop('disabled', true);
```

Will do.

But keep in mind after you disable it (by the above code) `onclick` handler wont work as its disabled. To enable it again add `$("#FullName").removeAttr('disabled');` in the `onclick` handler of another button or field.

Comment: Thank you for making the second part clear.  I could not figure out why the click event was not firing when the text input was disabled.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#checkbox-id').click(function()
{
    //If checkbox is checked then disable or enable input
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
        $("#to-enable-input").removeAttr("disabled"); 
        $("#to-disable-input").attr("disabled","disabled");
    }
    //If checkbox is unchecked then disable or enable input
    else
    {
        $("#to-enable-input").removeAttr("disabled"); 
        $("#to-disable-input").attr("disabled","disabled");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

another simple method to enable/disable input feild

```js
$("#anOtherButton").click(function() {
  $("#FullName").attr('disabled', !$("#FullName").attr('disabled'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="FullName" style="width: 299px" value="Marko" disabled="disabled" />
<br>
<br>
<input type="button" id="anOtherButton" value="disable/enable" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
$("#FullName").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Shiplu is correct, but use this if you have are not using jquery 1.6+

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#anOtherButton").click(function(){
  $("#FullName").attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
 });
```

- [.attr( attributeName, value) function](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

> Set one or more attributes for the set of matched elements

Comment: You forgot the `#` in the first selector `$("anOherButton")...` and it has typo.

Answer (score 0):

To toggle a field between disabled and enabled, try this:

```
$('#toggle_button').click(function () {
    $('#FullName').prop("disabled",

    function (i, val) {
        return !val;
    });
})
```