# Convert table cell to editable input

Tags: html, angular6

I want to create a table with 2 columns: `Name`, `Email`. Everytime I press the `edit button`, I want to transform the `td` into editable inputs. The problem is that if I have more users and I press the edit button, all users will become editable, not just the selected one. How can I solve this problem?

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let user of usersList">
      <td *ngIf="!editUser">{{ user.name }}</td>
      <td *ngIf="editUser"><input class=" form-control" size="1" type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.name"></td>

      <td *ngIf="!editUser">{{ user.email }}
      <td *ngIf="editUser"><input class=" form-control" size="1" type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.email"></td>

      <td *ngIf="!editUser">
        <a class="action-btn" (click)="onEdit()">
          <p class="material-icons pointer">edit</p>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

editUser: boolean = false
onEdit() {
  this.editUser = !this.editUser
}
```

How the table looks before pressing the red button
[image: How the table looks before pressing the red button]

How the table looks after pressing the button
[image: How the table looks after pressing the button]

Thank you for your time! ([this is what I want to achieve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38820134/how-do-i-change-html-table-cells-to-a-text-input-using-jquery?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it will work for you.

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let user of usersList; index as i">
      <td *ngIf="i!=selectedRowIndex">{{ user.name }}</td>
      <td *ngIf="selectedRowIndex == i"><input class=" form-control" size="1" 
        type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.name"></td>
          <td *ngIf="i!=selectedRowIndex">{{ user.email }}
      <td *ngIf="selectedRowIndex == i"><input class=" form-control" size="1" 
               type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.email"></td>
          <td>
        <a class="action-btn" (click)="onEdit(i)">
          <p class="material-icons pointer">edit</p>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

selectedRowIndex = -1
onEdit(rowIndex) {
  this.selectedRowIndex = rowIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an id for the user?

Then you could do something like:

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let user of usersList">
    <td *ngIf="editUserId !== user.id">{{ user.name }}</td>
    <td *ngIf="editUserId === user.id"><input [(ngModel)]="user.name"></td>

    <td *ngIf="editUserId !== user.id">{{ user.email }}
    <td *ngIf="editUserId === user.id"><input [(ngModel)]="user.email"></td>

    <td *ngIf="editUser !== user.id">
      <a class="action-btn" (click)="onEdit(user.id)">
        <p class="material-icons pointer">edit</p>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

and

```
editUserId: number;
onEdit(userId: number) {
  this.editUserId = userId;
}
```