# How to get the selected table row and rewrite the cells html in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

My bootstrap table is as follows... The table content and buttons are generated by php code but for the sake of simplicity, I will put the HTML only version:

```
<table id="usertable" class="table table-striped">
                <thead class="bg-light">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Username</th>
                        <th>First Name</a></th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Phone</th>
                        <th>Role ID</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="usertable1">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Josh96</td>
                        <td>Josh</td>
                        <td>Martin</td>
                        <td>613-737-0551</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td name="buttons">
                            <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                                <button id="buttonEdit" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" onclick="editRow(this);" style="">
                                    <i class="fs-6 bi-pencil-fill"></i>
                                </button>
                                <button id="buttonDelete" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" onclick="deleteRow(this);" style="">
                                    <i class="fs-6 bi-trash3-fill" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </button>
                                <button id="buttonSave" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" style="display: none;" onclick="saveChanges(this);">
                                    <i class="fs-6 bi-check-circle-fill"></i>
                                </button>
                                <button id="buttonCancel" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" style="display: none;" onclick="Cancel();">
                                    <i class="fs-6 bi-x-circle-fill" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

I am trying to change the html of a row's cells with JavaScript or jquery. For example, after clicking on the edit button, I want

```
<td>Josh96</td>
<td>Josh</td>
<td>Martin</td>
<td>613-737-0551</td>
<td>3</td>
```

to become

```
<td><input class= "form-control input-sm edit" id="username_Josh96" value ="Josh96"></input></td>
<td><input class= "form-control input-sm edit" id="firstname_Josh96" value ="Josh"></input></td>
<td><input class= "form-control input-sm edit" id="lastname_Josh96" value ="Martin"></input></td>
<td><input class= "form-control input-sm edit" id="Phone_Josh96" value ="613-737-0551"></input></td>
<td><input class= "form-control input-sm edit" id="RoleID_Josh96" value ="3"></input></td>
```

My javascript is as follows:

```
function editRow(r){
  var $row = $(r).parents('tr'); 
  var $cols = $row.find('td');
 //found out how get the current row content but haven't yet figured out how to change the html 
  console.log("current table row content: "+ $cols.text());
}
```

I know that I have to first Identify the row index, then extract the values of each cells, I'd put them in an array. I'd store the username in a variable in order to create my desired ids for each tds in the row and finally rewrite the html to have inputs. Being new in javascript, I haven't been able to figure it out yet

Comment: There are only 6 columns. The 6th doesn't have any name because it houses buttons.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change html table cells to a text-input using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38820134/how-do-i-change-html-table-cells-to-a-text-input-using-jquery)

Comment: @juan no it doesn't, his td's already have ids. Mine don't I'd like to be able to inject them.

Comment: you only need reference to the `row`, then you look through the row's `td` with [.each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) and replace the content of each one with an `input` and assign the value that the cell has

Comment: I'd start by writing code to deal with a single celled table. write a function that converts cell text to input via a button click. once you have that you should be able to apply it to any row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function editRow(r) {
    var $row = $(r).parents('tr');
    var username = $row.find('td').eq(0).text();
    var firstname = $row.find('td').eq(1).text();
    var lastname = $row.find('td').eq(2).text();
    var phone = $row.find('td').eq(3).text();
    var roleId = $row.find('td').eq(4).text();

    let newTr = '<td><input class= "form-control input-sm edit" id="username_' + username + '" value ="' + username + '"></input></td><td><input class= "form-control input-sm edit" id="firstname_' + username + '" value ="' + firstname + '"></input></td><td><input class= "form-control input-sm edit" id="lastname_' + username + '" value ="' + lastname + '"></input></td><td><input class= "form-control input-sm edit" id="Phone_' + username + '" value ="' + phone + '"></input></td><td><input class= "form-control input-sm edit" id="RoleID_' + username + '" value ="' + roleId + '"></input></td>';

    $row.html(newTr);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<table id="usertable" class="table table-striped">
   <thead class="bg-light">
      <tr>
         <th>Username</th>
         <th>First Name</a></th>
         <th>Last Name</th>
         <th>Phone</th>
         <th>Role ID</th>
         <th></th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="usertable1">
      <tr>
         <td>Josh96</td>
         <td>Josh</td>
         <td>Martin</td>
         <td>613-737-0551</td>
         <td>3</td>
         <td name="buttons">
            <div class="btn-group pull-right">
               <button id="buttonEdit" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" onclick="editRow(this);" style="">E
               <i class="fs-6 bi-pencil-fill"></i>
               </button>
               <button id="buttonDelete" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" onclick="deleteRow(this);" style="">D
               <i class="fs-6 bi-trash3-fill" aria-hidden="true"></i>
               </button>
               <button id="buttonSave" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" style="display: none;" onclick="saveChanges(this);">
               <i class="fs-6 bi-check-circle-fill"></i>
               </button>
               <button id="buttonCancel" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" style="display: none;" onclick="Cancel();">
               <i class="fs-6 bi-x-circle-fill" aria-hidden="true"></i>
               </button>
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```