# Enable and Disable input fields on click button using jquery (laravel5.3)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button which looks like an **on off Button** 
[image: Button looks as]

Button is by default **on** but when user will click it should get **off** and when it is clicked it should disable the input field
 my button is as

**Button**

```
<input type="checkbox" class="make-switch" id="on_off" name="double_optin" checked data-on-text="on" data-off-text="off">
```

**Input field** which i want to be **disabled** if above button clicks

```
<div class="col-md-4 FullName">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ isset($student->email) ? $student->email : '' }}" required />
 </div>
```

My **Jquery** code is as

```
$('#on_off').click(function(){
    $('.FullName').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

I took above help from [Disable Input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649877/how-to-disable-enable-input-field-on-click-with-jquery)

Help Please its not working for me

Comment: You want to disable Input field , Right?

Comment: yes disable and also enable if its clicked again

Comment: But i applied Fullname Class To DIV

Comment: Bootstrap has readymade toggle button.

Answer (score 2):

First of your code is missing something. Like the control with class `FullName`

You can get the value of the checkbox by using `$('#on_off').is(':checked')` or in this case `$(this).is(':checked')` because we are using `$('#on_off')` click event.

Since you dont have a "Fullname" class anywhere in your example I added `email` to the `Id` field of the `input`

```js
$('#on_off').click(function() {

  $('.FullName [name="email"]').attr('disabled', $(this).is(':checked') ? false : true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="make-switch" checked id="on_off" name="double_optin" data-on-text="on" data-off-text="off">

<div class="col-md-4 FullName">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="disable me by click on checkbox" required />
</div>
```

Comment: If you read my post, you will notice that i said there are some parts of your code that is missing. `$('.FullName')` dont exist in the example of your code. Please update your question or be a bit more clear about what dont work

Comment: dear i added Full name class in my input please review my question

Comment: dear you removed checked class from button it will be checked by default and input should enable.

Comment: You want the checkbox to be checked by default and the input shall be enable(writeable) by default?

Comment: try look at it now.

Comment: at 1st uncheck its remains enable please run code snippet

Comment: Okay please clarify your question. checkbox checked = input enable?

Comment: check it now, if this is not what you want then you need to clarify what you want way more

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.

Here is your updated code:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="make-switch" id="on_off" name="double_optin" checked data-on-text="on" data-off-text="off">
<div class="col-md-4 FullName">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ isset($student->email) ? $student->email : '' }}" id= "email"required />
 </div>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#on_off').change(function() {
        //alert();
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            $('.FullName input').prop('disabled', false);
        }
        else {
            $('.FullName input').prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Hope, this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

use `.attr('disabled',true)` or `.removeAttr('disabled')` instead of `.prop('disabled', true);` if not working.

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest you can get.

Create a checkbox. In click event of checkbox, pass its state as a boolean to buttons disabled value.

Though I would suggest to use ready made toggle button. Link is [**here**](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(":checkbox").change(function(){
    $(":button").prop("disabled",$(this).is(":checked"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=checkbox />
<input type=button value=Target />
```