# jQuery disable all button of a css class and input type button

Tags: jquery

```
<input class="submit2" type="button" name="submit2"  value="Submit" id="submit1" onclick="">
```

I want to disable the button on my page after clicking it. to avoid double click.

i have tried following code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.submit2').click(function() {

        $("input.submit2").attr('disabled', true);

    });
});​
```

but it is working only when the input type of button is submit not button.

how to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to select twice what you already have selected:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.submit2').click(function() { 
        $(this).attr('disabled', true);
    }); 
});
```

`$(this)` in this case refers to the button you just clicked

Answer (score 1):

also,inorder to make it compatible with all browser, the value of disabled attr should be "disabled"

use it like

```
$("input.submit2").attr('disabled',"disabled");
```

The above solution is perfect if you are using jquery version 1.5 and earlier and if you are using jQuery 1.6+ then use prop to set attribute

```
$("input.submit2").prop('disabled',true); // here jQuery will normalize the value and set the property
```

Comment: `disabled` variable is undefined

Comment: jQuery normalizes boolean attributes and allows true/false to be passed afaik.

Comment: @zerkms: it should be string so changed it.

Comment: @sg3s: JQuery version 1.5 and earlier, the `attr('disabled',true)` was not setting up disabled properly across browsers. so we need to set value as "disabled" not true. here is one similar post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414365/how-to-disable-an-input-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

It's an old school HTML relic.  The attribute value is 'disabled'='disabled':

```
$("input.submit2").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it now:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var $submitButton = $(this, "input[type='submit']");
     $submitButton.attr("disabled", "true");
});
```