# Make a submit clickable after validations are met

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html:

```
<p>Genre: {{ create_production_form.genre }}</p>
<p>Privacy: {{ create_production_form.privacy }}</p>
<p><input type="submit" name="next" value="Next" disabled="disabled"></p>
```

How would I make the `next` button clickable only after Genre and Privacy are filled in? For example, something like:

```
if ($("id_genre").val() && $("id_privacy").val()) {
    $("input[name=next]").attr("disabled","")
}
```

The only thing is, it'd need to be 'live', so it can detect when all these fields are filled in.

Comment: Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594952/jquery-disable-enable-submit-button)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wut? The 'event' handles the delegation, so the 'event handler' needs to have `live()` or `on()` depending on the version of jQuery you're using. This means that an essential piece of the equation has been left out.

The 'event' methods I'm speaking of are `submit`, `change` or `click`. You must delegate the code to one of these events -- using the aforementioned `live()` or `on()` methods.

Otherwise, if you're just simply looking to enable them if data has been fille din.

```
$('form :input').change(function(){
  if ($("id_genre").val() && $("id_privacy").val()) {
    $("input[name=next]").attr("disabled","")
  }
});
```

This wil check the form to see if the inputs change, if they do, it will test the values and you'll get your result.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they're both text-inputs, you could validate on `keyup`, otherwise validating on `change` would also work.

Answer (score 0):

try using on hover cause user has to hover over the button before click i hope it helps

```
$("input[name=next]").hover(function() {


    if ($("id_genre").val()!="" && $("id_privacy").val()!="") {
        $("input[name=next]").removeAttr("disabled")
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('form').change(function() {
    if ($("id_genre").val().length > 0 && $("id_privacy").val().length > 0) {
        $("input[type='submit']").prop("disabled", false)
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/8AtAz/1/

In the demo when you click the valid button it will enable the next button: Please lemme know if I missed any point.

**code**

```
$("input[type='submit']").prop('disabled', true);
$("#valid").click(function() {

    $("input[type='submit']").prop('disabled', false);
})​
```

**OR** In your case

```
 if ($("id_genre").val() != "" && $("id_privacy").val() != "") {
        $("input[type='submit']").prop("disabled", false)
    }
```