# how to enable text area or input type="text" using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

am having the code as follows when clicked on radio button yes the text box has to be enabled if not it has to be disabled. please someone help me. thanks

```
<div class="label_left">
    <label>Does the tourism office operate on a biennial budget? : (Y/N)</label>
</div>
<div class="text_right">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="high" name="high" />
    <label>Y</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" id="high" name="high" />
    <label>N</label>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
</div>
<div class="label_left">
    <label>If YES,please indicate when the current biennial budget began: (mm/dd/yy)</label>
</div>
<div class="text_right">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="date_biennial_budget" id="date_biennial_budget" value="" size="30" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable an input with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414365/how-to-disable-an-input-with-jquery)

Comment: check y answer posted very short and easy code...!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**first of all make sure your id is unique..**

use `prop()` to enable/disable elements.. (**make sure you add value to your radio button... which is missing in your code** )

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" id="high" value="Y" name="high"  />
<input type="radio" id="high" value="N" name="high"  />
```

**jquery**

```
 $('input[name="high"]').change(function(){
      if($(this).val() == 'Y'){
         $('#date_biennial_budget').prop('disabled',false);
      }else{
         $('#date_biennial_budget').prop('disabled',true);
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

It's easy with jQuery > 1.6

```
$('input').prop('disabled',true)
$('input').prop('disabled',false)
```

To react to your radio button, you have to give each one a different value attribute (1 for yes?) and listen to the `change` event.

```
$("#date_biennial_budget").change(function(){

    if($(this).val() == 1) 
       $('input[name=high]').prop('disabled',false);
    else 
       $('input[name=high]').prop('disabled',true);
}
```

Comment: This will disable the entire `input` tag inclusing radio, button etc

Answer (score 1):

```
if($('#high').is(":selected") {
   $('input').prop('disabled',true);
} else {
   $('input').prop('disabled',false);
}
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

Use this for text-box,

```
$('input[type=text]').prop('disabled',true);
```

**UPDATES:** 
Since you have used `label` tag, you use `for` attribute like below

```
<input type="radio" id="highY" name="high" />
<label for="highY">Y</label>
<input type="radio" id="highN" name="high" />
<label for="highN">N</label>
```

Assign the `id` of the respective `input` to the `for` attribute in `label`

Based on this you can do like this

```
$('input[name=high]').on('change', function () {
    var label = $('label[for=' + this.id + ']').text();
    if (label === "Y") {
        $('#date_biennial_budget').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $('#date_biennial_budget').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vLfzn/)