# Preventing Double Clicks on image map areas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, double-click

I have a basic image **map** that executes a javascript/jquery routine when an **area** is clicked. At the moment, the `DoStuff()` method is executed twice if the area is double-clicked. Can anyone provide a method that will prevent double execution in a double-click scenario?

```
<img src="images/myimage.png" border="0" usemap="#Map1" />
<map name="Map1">
    <area coords="5,115,97,150" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="DoStuff()">
    <area coords="104,116,199,149" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="DoStuff()">
</map>
```

Comment: A pretty basic and brute force method would be to just add a timer/interval within DoStuff() and check if an appropriate amount of time has passed before you would like to allow it to run again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a boolean flag.

```
var hasBeenClicked = false;

// Your code...

if(!hasBeenClicked){
    hasBeenClicked = true;

    // My routine

    setTimeout(function(){ // McPhelpsius's idea (wait for 1sec before we can click again)
        hasBeenClicked = false; // My routine is over, we can click again
    }, 1000);
 } else {
    // do nothing 
 }
```

Comment: what about setTimeout(1000)?  That might be useful for adding a full second in between the time that it is clickable.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery you can include this at the top of the click handler.  On click it will disable the element which stops any click events from happening.

```
function DoStuff() {
    $('[name="Map1"]').prop('disabled', true);
    //Do Stuff..
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414365/how-to-disable-enable-an-input-with-jquery) explains some other options depending on your jQuery version.

Comment: Just tried it and it does not prevent the double execution... I am calling window.open in this method and I always get two windows opening.