# <select> tag posting all data when style="display:none;"

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have main categories and Sub categories of products when I select any main category it shows related sub-categories. But When I post the form it posts last sub-category value instead of selected sub-category value.

JavaScript Code

```
   $(function() {
    $('#category').change(function(){
        $('.sub-category').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
    });
});
```

HTML code

```
 <Select id="category" name="product_category">
  <option value="eco">Main Category 1</option>
 <option value="organic">Main Category 2</option>
  </Select>

  <Select name="product_sub" id="eco" class="sub-category">
  <option value="eco1">Sub Category 1</option>
  <option value="eco2">Sub Category 2</option>
   </Select>

<Select id="organic" name="product_sub" class="sub-category" style="display:none;width:270px;">
  <option value="organic1">Sub Category 3</option>
   <option value="organic2">Sub Category 4</option>
 </Select>
```

For Example: When I am selecting sub category 1 , its posting value of sub category 3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All *successful* form fields are submitted to the server.  CSS `display` does not impact whether or not a form field is considered successful.  [The HTML spec defines what makes a control successful.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2)

> A successful control is "valid" for submission. Every successful
>   control has its control name paired with its current value as part of
>   the submitted form data set. A successful control must be defined
>   within a FORM element and must have a control name.
>
> However:
>
> - Controls that are disabled cannot be successful.
> - If a form contains more than one submit button, only the activated submit button is successful.
> - All "on" checkboxes may be successful.
> - For radio buttons that share the same value of the name attribute, only the "on" radio button may be successful.
> - For menus, the control name is provided by a SELECT element and values are provided by OPTION elements. Only selected options may be
>     successful. When no options are selected, the control is not
>     successful and neither the name nor any values are submitted to the
>     server when the form is submitted.
> - The current value of a file select is a list of one or more file names. Upon submission of the form, the contents of each file are
>     submitted with the rest of the form data. The file contents are
>     packaged according to the form's content type.
> - The current value of an object control is determined by the object's implementation.
>
> If a control doesn't have a current value when the form is submitted,
>   user agents are not required to treat it as a successful control.
>
> Furthermore, user agents should not consider the following controls
>   successful:
>
> - Reset buttons.
> - OBJECT elements whose declare attribute has been set.
>
> Hidden controls and controls that are not rendered because of style
>   sheet settings may still be successful.

[Disable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1414366/201952) the form fields you do not want submitted.

```
$('#category').change(function(){
    $('.sub-category').hide().prop('disabled', true);
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show().prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Comment: Any solution for solving this problem, so that it posts only selected field.

Comment: @AkashSharma: [Disable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1414366/201952) the form fields you do not want submitted.