# enable and disable textbox by using button click

Tags: jquery, html

I have multiple of textbox...each textbox have own button to enable or disable .
How to do it ?
I have already try this

```
$('#disablebutton').click(function(){
$('#textfieldToClose').attr('disable');
});

<input type="text" name="text11" readonly="readonly" id="textfieldToClose">
<input type="button" value="edit" name="button1" id="disablebutton">
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable/enable an input with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414365/how-to-disable-enable-an-input-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#disablebutton').click(function(){
    if($('#textfieldToClose').prop('disabled'))
    {
     $('#textfieldToClose').prop('disabled', false)
    }
    else{
         $('#textfieldToClose').prop('disabled', true)
      }
    });
})
```

or with Read only:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#disablebutton').click(function(){
    if($('#textfieldToClose').prop('readonly'))
    {
     $('#textfieldToClose').removeAttr('readonly');
    }
    else{
         $('#textfieldToClose').attr('readonly', 'readonly')
      }
    });
});
```

Because you only select the attr but, don't do anything with.
[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AvEP7/1/)

Comment: hi your demo is work very nice ... but when i do it on my ... still not function

Comment: i found the problem ~ by the way thanks you so much !

Comment: sorry now have some question ... how to do this in multiple textbox? because each textbox have own edit button

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50816/discussion-between-frozen-and-freak-droid)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#disablebutton').click(function(){
   $(this).prev().attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NLvBT/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#disablebutton').click(function(){
  $('#textfieldToClose').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //sett the `disabled` attribute on the    element
});
```

`$('#textfieldToClose').attr('disable')` did not work because you were just quering an attribute `disable` on the element which doesn't even exist. The correct name is `disabled`