# Issue trying to Disable/Enable a textbox JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to use a piece of code that enables and disables textboxes on a button click. Someone has solved this previously  [enable and disable textbox by using button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23117877/enable-and-disable-textbox-by-using-button-click) . Their Demo works exactly the way I want but when I copy and paste the exact code onto my html it doesn't work. I even tried pasting it into a completely blank html page and it still doesn't work.. Any ideas why? Thanks.

Wilfredo P's code ---

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#disablebutton').click(function(){
if($('#textfieldToClose').prop('disabled'))
{
 $('#textfieldToClose').prop('disabled', false)
}
else{
     $('#textfieldToClose').prop('disabled', true)
  }
});
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AvEP7/1/

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me, do you want the field to clear out on disable? If so, try this:

```
 $('#textfieldToClose').prop('disabled', true).val('')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AvEP7/11/

Comment: Yea it works fine in fiddle but I just copied the exact code to my html and tried it and it doesn't work... Can't understand why