# Change button text but preserve default behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some simple jQuery to change the text of a button once it's clicked

```
<button type="submit" id="zipUploadButton" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>

$uploadButton.click(function(){
  $(this).text('please wait').attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

The trouble is it seems doing this blocks default behavior (a form submission, which I still want to happen). Is there a way to make sure the default behavior is preserved or an alternate way to do what I'm trying above that would work?

Comment: Please share the whole script. What is $uploadButton, etc...

Comment: [Controls that are disabled cannot be successful.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the button in form submit event instead of the click event. The following code assume `$form` contains the parent form of `$uploadButton`.

```
$form.submit(function(){
    $uploadButton.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `timeout` to remove the disabled attribute in order to submit:

**For JQuery 1.6+:**

```
$('#zipUploadButton').click(function(){
    var button = $(this);
    button.prop('disabled', true);
    setTimeout(function() {
         button.prop('disabled', false);
    },1000);
    $("#form1").submit();
});
```

Otherwise, as mentioned in the comments, a form cannot be submitted if the button is disabled: [more info](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2)

**For JQuery 1.5 and below:**

To set the disabled attribute, you could use:

```
button.attr('disabled','disabled');
```

And to enable again, use `.removeAttr()`

```
button.removeAttr('disabled');
```

**[Credits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414365/how-to-disable-enable-an-input-with-jquery)**

Comment: Should use `prop` to toggle `disabled`

Comment: You are right! Updated it... for JQuery 1.6+ you would want `prop` :). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to delay disabling the button until after the event has completed. Something like this should help you.

```
$uploadButton.click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.text('please wait');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $this.attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }, 10);
});
```