# disabled/enabled button - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to disabled and enable a submit-input type depending on the completeness user's input with jquery. I am able to shut it down but cant not turn it on :(

```
$('#submit_btn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

var nameFlag = false;;
var emailFlag = false;
var pwdFlag = false;

$('#f-name').focusout(function() {
    if($(this).val() == '') {
        nameFlag = false;
    } else if($(this).val().length < 4) {
        nameFlag = false;
    } else {
        nameFlag = true;
        //alert(nameFlag);
    }
});


$('#f-email').focusout(function() {
    if($(this).val() == '') {
        emailFlag = false;
    } else if($(this).val().length < 4) {
        emailFlag = false;
    } else {
        emailFlag = true;
        //alert(emailFlag);
    }
});


$('#f-pwd').focusout(function() {
    if($(this).val() == '') {
        pwdFlag = false;
    } else if($(this).val().length < 6) {
        pwdFlag = false;
    } else {
        pwdFlag = true;
        //alert(pwdFlag);
    }
});

//alert(nameFlag + " " + emailFlag + " " + pwdFlag);
if(nameFlag && emailFlag && pwdFlag) {
    $('#submit_btn').removeAttr('disabled');
} else {
    $('#submit_btn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

So I put some alert boxes and see that my flags change depending on the user input but it doesn't enable my submit button

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable/enable an input with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414365/how-to-disable-enable-an-input-with-jquery)

Comment: Yep, I couldn't find that post. Anyway, after finish reading the post, I think my code is similar on set/remove attribute disabled except that I have a boolean to control that action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:
http://jsfiddle.net/jq7Q7/1/
i moved yourr check code to a new function and check it every time you focus out a control:

```
    $('#submit_btn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    var nameFlag = false;;
    var emailFlag = false;
    var pwdFlag = false;

    $('#f-name').focusout(function() {
        if($(this).val() == '') {
            nameFlag = false;
        } else if($(this).val().length < 4) {
            nameFlag = false;
        } else {
            nameFlag = true;
            //alert(nameFlag);
        }
         checkform();
    });


    $('#f-email').focusout(function() {
        if($(this).val() == '') {
            emailFlag = false;
        } else if($(this).val().length < 4) {
            emailFlag = false;
        } else {
            emailFlag = true;
            //alert(emailFlag);
        }
         checkform();
    });


    $('#f-pwd').focusout(function() {
        if($(this).val() == '') {
            pwdFlag = false;
        } else if($(this).val().length < 6) {
            pwdFlag = false;
        } else {
            pwdFlag = true;
            //alert(pwdFlag);
        }
         checkform();
    });
    function checkform(){
        //alert(nameFlag + " " + emailFlag + " " + pwdFlag);
        if(nameFlag && emailFlag && pwdFlag) {
            $('#submit_btn').removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            $('#submit_btn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. But I'm not quiet sure, why my code is not working. (I'm new to jquery so I would like to learn more about it).

Comment: your code not worked because you check your flag when paage loaded(all fields are empty and flags are false), you should to check your flags every time an input changes

Answer (score 2):

I also tried to do same using jquery attr. its working fine. are you doing code inside document ready?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit_btn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    var nameFlag = false;
    var emailFlag = false;
    var pwdFlag = false;
    $("#fName").focusout(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            DisabledButton();
        } else if ($(this).val().length < 4) {
            DisabledButton();
        } else {
            EnabledButton();
        }
    });


    $('#f-email').focusout(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            DisabledButton()
        } else if ($(this).val().length < 4) {
            DisabledButton();
        } else {
            EnabledButton();
        }
    });

    function EnabledButton() {
        $('#submit_btn').removeAttr('disabled');
    }

    function DisabledButton() {
        $('#submit_btn').attr('disabled', 'disabled')
    }
});
```

see fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/2jDKm/2/

Answer (score 0):

you can use prop() method insted of attr()

```
$('#submit_btn').prop('disabled', true);
```

and

```
$('#submit_btn').prop('disabled', false);
```

can help you through this problem

Comment: I just changed to prop() function and it doesn't work either. I suggest that it never hit to the true condition of the if statement, although the flags are changed.

Comment: can you post your html here? or jsFiddle link

Answer (score 0):

This is my html:

```
<form class="form_box prefix_clear" method="get" action="#login">
    <div class="f-field">
        <label for="f-name">Username:</label><br/>
        <input id="f-name" class="submit_text" type="text" name="username"/>
        <p class="f-error case1">Please enter your username</p>
        <p class="f-error case2">Your username has to be at least 4 characters</p>
    </div>
    <div class="f-field">
        <label for="f-email">Email:</label><br/>
        <input id="f-email" class="submit_text" type="text" name="email"/>
        <p class="f-error case1">Please enter your email</p>
        <p class="f-error case2">Your email is not a valid format</p>
    </div>
    <div  class="f-field">
        <label for="f-pwd">Password:</label><br/>
        <input id="f-pwd" class="submit_text" type="password" name="password"/>
        <p class="f-error case1">Please enter your password</p>
        <p class="f-error case2">Your password has to be at least 6 letters (A-Z, a-z, 0-9)</p>
    </div>
    <div class="prefix_clear">
        <input id="submit_btn" class="f-btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Account"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

something wrong with your variables. try this code its working fine.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit_btn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    var nameFlag = false;;
    var emailFlag = false;
    var pwdFlag = false;

    $('#f-name').focusout(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            DisabledButton();
        } else if ($(this).val().length < 4) {
            DisabledButton();
        } else {
            EnabledButton();
            //alert(nameFlag);
        }
    });


    $('#f-email').focusout(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            DisabledButton();
        } else if ($(this).val().length < 4) {
            DisabledButton();
        } else {
            EnabledButton();
            //alert(emailFlag);
        }
    });


    $('#f-pwd').focusout(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            DisabledButton();
        } else if ($(this).val().length < 6) {
            DisabledButton();
        } else {
            EnabledButton();
        }
    });

    function EnabledButton() {
        $('#submit_btn').removeAttr('disabled');
    }

    function DisabledButton() {
        $('#submit_btn').attr('disabled', 'disabled')
    }
});
```

see jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/2jDKm/4/