# Re-enabling a disabled button

Tags: jquery, html

If I set a button's `disabled` attribute to be `true`, and I then want to enable it after a certain period of time using jQuery, why can I not then just set the `disabled` attribute to be `false` with the jQuery?

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input id="myButton" type="submit" disabled="true" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
setTimeout(EnableSubmit, 3000);

function EnableSubmit()
{
    $("#myButton").attr("disabled", "false");
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TV7t4/

Answer (score 4):

The disabled attribute's value doesn't matter, it just needs to be set to work.

Try removing the attribute entirely like this:

```
$("#myButton").removeAttr("disabled");
```

Answer (score 3):

I always use this, which worked for me:

```
$("#myButton").prop('disabled', false);
```

Also see this: [Disable/enable an input with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414365/how-to-disable-enable-an-input-with-jquery)

Answer (score 3):

Because the `disabled` attribute is a *boolean attribute*. It works by its mere presence, regardless of its value. I could write `disabled="I'm a broken paperclip"` and it would still work.

Try:

```
document.getElementById('myButton').disabled = true; // disable
document.getElementById('myButton').disabled = false; // re-enable
```

[Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) is so much simpler...

Answer (score 3):

Use `.prop()` and `false`:

```
setTimeout(EnableSubmit, 3000);
function EnableSubmit() {
    $("#myButton").prop("disabled", false);
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/TV7t4/3/)**

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/prop/): The .prop() method should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the .attr() method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set it to the boolean value `false`, not the string `"false"`, so lose the quotes.

```
$("#myButton").prop("disabled", false);
```

}

Comment: Don't forget `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`. From the docs: The .prop() method should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the .attr() method.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#myButton").removeAttr('disabled');
```