# IE 11 Migration issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, internet-explorer

We are migrating our application from IE 8 to IE 11 and found a strange issue. 
Below jquery code which worked fined in IE8 is not working in IE11.

$("#Submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");

Can anyone help me with IE 11 equivalent code for the above code?

Comment: Use $("#Submit").prop("disabled", true); instead

Answer (score 0):

This should work in jQuery <1.6. If you're using jQuery 1.6+ you should use the `prop` method:

```
// disable
$("#Submit").prop("disabled", true);
// enable
$("#Submit").prop("disabled", false);
```

see [Disable/enable an input with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414365/disable-enable-an-input-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#Submit").prop("disabled", true);
```

or

```
$("#Submit").attr("disabled", true);
```

This might help you.