# how to disable input text value of current row using script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
function bangali() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".amtcollected").keyup(function() {
            $(".amtcollected1").attr("disabled", true);
        });
        $(".amtcollected1").keyup(function() {
            $(".amtcollected").attr("disabled", true);
        });
    });
}
bangali();
```

Comment: Share your HTML and post a problem question describing your problem and also give proper title

Comment: You don't need `bangali` function. `ready` is sufficient

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable/enable an input with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414365/disable-enable-an-input-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

You should use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop2):

```
.prop('disabled', true);
```

Also, you can simplify and rewrite it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.amtcollected, .amtcollected1').keyup(function(event) {
        $(event.currentTarget).prop('disabled', true);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't pass a boolean value but the string `"disabled"`

```
.attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Comment: either that or use prop("disabled", true);

Comment: Really you should use prop for disabled as it's a property not an attribute though in reality both will work.

Answer (score 1):

find row index by

```
var row_index = $(this).parent('table').index();
```

and set disabled

```
$("table").eq(row_index).disabled = true;
```

I didn't test it

Answer (score 0):

jQuery 1.6+ use prop()

```
$('#id').on('event_name', function() {
    $("input").prop('disabled', true);   //Disable input
    $("input").prop('disabled', false);  //Enable input 
})
```

jQuery 1.5 and below use attr()

```
$('#id').on('event_name', function() {
    $("input").attr('disabled','disabled');   //Disable input
    $("input").removeAttr('disabled');  //Enable input 
})
```

***NOTE***: Do not use `.removeProp()` method to remove native properties such as checked, disabled, or selected. This will remove the property completely and, once removed, cannot be added again to element. Use .prop() to set these properties to false instead.