# Two textbox same value in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have select box and two (2) textboxes.

I want the value of select box that displays on the first textbox and whatever the value of the first textbox it display also in the second box.

select box = first textbox
first textbox = second textbox

Buy the way my first textbox is readonly so there is no way to trigger the input, keyup, keydown event. I want my two (2) textbox the same value every time.

I have the html code.

```html
<select id="selectbox">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
</select>


<input id="first-textbox" type="text" readonly>
<input id="second-textbox type="text">
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: If the first textbox is readonly, how does it change? Just change that code so it updates both textboxes. I don't think there's a way to make that happen automatically.

Comment: I can use input[type=hidden] also as my first textbox. What I really want is the two textbox same value everytime without typing on it. I want to detect changes on the first textbox to displays the value on the second textbox

Comment: I also used this code $("#first-textbox").on("input propertychange") but that works when you type on the textbox

Comment: checkout this http://jsfiddle.net/nafnR/727/

Answer (score 1):

> I want the value of select box that displays on the first textbox and
>   whatever the value of the first textbox it display also in the second
>   box.
>
> select box = first textbox first textbox = second textbox

Try utilizing selector `$("#selectbox, :text:not([readonly])")` ; `input` , `change` event ; `.val()` to set both `input type="text"` values

```js
$("#selectbox, :text:not([readonly])").on("input change", function(e) {
  $(":text").val(this.value)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<select id="selectbox">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
</select>


<input id="first-textbox" type="text" readonly>
<input id="second-textbox type="text">
```

Answer (score 1):

First change:

```
<input id="second-textbox type="text">
```

To:

```
<input id="second-textbox" type="text">
```

Then use the following to accomplish your goal:

```js
$('#selectbox, #second-textbox').on('change input', function() {
    var sel = $(this).is('#selectbox') ? '#first-textbox' : '#first-textbox,#second-textbox';
    $( sel ).val( this.value );
})
.filter('#selectbox').change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectbox">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
</select>


<input id="first-textbox" type="text" readonly>
<input id="second-textbox" type="text">
```

Comment: is there's a way the value of second textbox not depends on any changes in select box? I mean whatever changes in first textbox displays in second textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1 (best fits my eyes)

HTML

```
<select id="selectbox">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript

```
$('#selectbox').on('change', function() {
    $("#first-textbox").val($(this).val());
    $("#second-textbox").val($(this).val());
});
```

[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/leo128/w2br2xb4/2/)

Solution 2 (Best fits the question):

```
$('#selectbox').on('change', function() {
    $("#first-textbox").val($(this).val()).trigger('keyup');
});

$('#first-textbox').on('keyup', function() {
    $("#second-textbox").val($(this).val());
});
```

[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/leo128/w2br2xb4/12/)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the text on change:

```js
$(function() {
  var tbs = $('input[id$=-textbox]'); //cache all
  $('#selectbox').on('change', function(e) {
    tbs.val(this.value); //set text box value
  }).trigger('change'); // force value on page load
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectbox">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>


<input id="first-textbox" type="text" readonly='' />
<input id="second-textbox" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I built upon @Rafael Topasi's solution posted in the comment above in his jsFiddle.  All I did was add the functionality that you outlined in your question, which was to disable the first text input field and make it so that second input field is **equal** to the first input field when the select option changes.

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dixalex/nafnR/728/)

```js
//StackOverflow Solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32238975/two-textbox-same-value-in-jquery
//Disable Input: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414365/disable-enable-an-input-with-jquery
//Source: http://jsfiddle.net/nafnR/727/ by Rafael Topasi
//08-26-2015
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input#first-textbox").prop('disabled', true);
  //$("input").prop('disabled', false);
  $("#selectbox option").filter(function() {
    return $(this).val() == $("#first-textbox").val();
  }).attr('selected', true);

  $("#selectbox").on("propertychange change", function() {

    $("#first-textbox").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("value"));
    $("#second-textbox").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("value"));
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectbox" name="name">
  <option value="">Please select...</option>
  <option value="Elvis">Elvis</option>
  <option value="Frank">Frank</option>
  <option value="Jim">Jim</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="first-textbox" name="firstname" value="Elvis" oninput="document.getElementById('second-textbox').value=this.value">
<input id="second-textbox" type="text" name="firstname" value="">
```