# Disable an input on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to disable an input on submit but it didn't work. I have a select and I want that if it has a certain value it won't be passed in parameter (here the value is "autres") and if this value is selected an input appear and user can type what they want. Here is what I have :

```
<select name="motif" id="motif" onChange="choix()">
                <option value="">-</option>
                <option value="formation">Formation</option>
                <option value="autres">Autres</option>
</select>
<div id="commentaire"></div>
<input type="submit" value="Envoyer ma demande" id="submit" onClick="disableMotif()"/>
```

**Javascript**

```
function choix()
{
    var i = document.getElementById("motif").value;
    var comment = document.getElementById("comment");
    if (i=='autres' && !comment)
      {
        $( "#commentaire" ).append( "<div id=\"comment\"> Indiquez le motif : <input type=\"text\" style=\"margin-top:5px;\" name=\"motif\" value=\"\"/></div>" );
      }
      else{
        comment.parentNode.removeChild(comment);
      }
  }
function disableMotif()
{
    var i = document.getElementById("motif").value;
    var comment = document.getElementById("comment");
    if (i=='autres' && !comment)
      {
        $("#motif").prop('disabled', true);
      }
}
```

The function for disable the input on submit doesn't work. I have in the parameters 2 times "motif". How can I do this ?

Comment: you can take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/1414366/2798643

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable/enable an input with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414365/disable-enable-an-input-with-jquery)

Comment: Are you sure your code pass this condition: `if (i=='autres' && !comment)`???

Comment: @GovindaRajbhar BUT that's what is already using OP, no?!

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes, wrong condition

Comment: @SimonM. I'm not sure what you mean in your comment. Is your condition correct or not? Just as a sdie note, mixing jQuery with javascript native method like in your code is for sure a no go. Your code is quite unreadable imho  EDIT: i see your anwser now :)

Comment: @A.Wolff How can I improve this part of code ? And why it is a no go ? :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you see this one ? [Disable/enable an input with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414365/disable-enable-an-input-with-jquery)

It can depends on your jQuery version. Try with the attr method instead of prop :

```
$("input").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

or directly :

```
$("#motif").disabled = true;
```

Comment: Yes, I've seen this one, I'm using jQuery 1.7

Comment: Have you erros in console javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, just a wrong `if` condition. I needed to check only : `if (i=='autres')`
and not if `comment` wasn't displayed