# Start with a link disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

I have a select menu with a link to redirect the customer once he/she selects the option that he/she wants. My question would be: how I can start with the link disabled with javascript to force the customer to select one of the options?
Below I paste the code that I have:

```
<select name="dept" class="select_type" id="PT_Certificate_options">
    <option value="#">Select Study Option</option>
    <option value="mydomain.com/option1">Distance</option>
    <option value="mydomain.com/option2">Part Time</option>
    <option value="mydomain.com/option3">Full Time</option>
</select>
<a id="certificate_enrol_link" href="#" class="orange_btn">ENROL NOW</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#PT_Certificate_options").change(function () {
        console.log(this.value);
        $("#certificate_enrol_link").attr('href', this.value);
    });
</script>
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you would have to use full URLs when appending the href to these `a`'s, because otherwise your URL's will not work. 
Second, since I noticed your ENROL NOW `a` has a `class="orange_btn",` I'm assuming you want it to be a submit button instead of a text link. Disabling a button is a lot easier than disabling a text link, so I changed it into a button for you.

Here is the final working example (provided you have jQuery loaded, which you have, I presume):

```js
$("#PT_Certificate_options").change(function() {
  console.log(this.value);
  if (this.value != "#") {
    $("#certificate_enrol_link").prop('disabled', false)
  } else {
    $("#certificate_enrol_link").prop('disabled', true)
  }
});

$("#certificate_enrol_link").click(function() {
  window.location.href = $('#PT_Certificate_options').val();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="dept" class="select_type" id="PT_Certificate_options">
  <option value="#">Select Study Option</option>
  <option value="http://example.com/option1">Distance</option>
  <option value="http://example.com/option2">Part Time</option>
  <option value="http://example.com/option3">Full Time</option>
</select>
<button id="certificate_enrol_link" href="#" class="orange_btn" disabled>ENROL NOW</button>
```

Edit: as Musa kindly pointed out, buttons cannot have href's, so I had to make a slight alteration to make the button actually redirect to the selected link, but the above example works now :)

Comment: buttons don't have hrefs

Comment: Thank you Musa, I was just about to try to do the 'a's in grey myself but I didn't figure out how yet :)

Comment: I have updated the example to circumvent the "buttons don't have hrefs" problem. Thank you for pointing this out. It's a fully working example now. Keep in mind the redirect to example.com might not work in this snippet preview, but if you copy-paste it to your website, it will work!

Comment: You should really be using a button for this sort of thing +1

Comment: perfect +1  you can use short IF   $("#certificate_enrol_link").prop('disabled',(this.value != "#")?0:1) ;   prop vs attr jQuery ver http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414365/disable-enable-an-input-with-jquery

Answer (score 7):

Just start with no href attribute:

```
<a id="certificate_enrol_link" class="orange_btn">ENROL NOW</a>
```

Comment: This is the best answer. Occam's Razor, the simplest answer is often correct. And for original person who asked you can even spice it up with some CSS to make it clear the link is disabled. And remove that class once you add the href. I can't believe how many answers are using JavaScript.

Comment: AtheistP3ace, this answer will still require the javascript that appends the href, so I'm not really certain what you mean by "I can't believe how many answers are using JavaScript"... He will still need javascript to re-enable the link! Furthermore, looking at the fact that he's using a class="orange_btn", this tells me he is probably going to format the link as a button. So why not use a real button then? You don't need javascript to disable a button (you just add the attribute 'disabled'), and you can enable it very easily with one line of javascript. It will even look great, without css!

Comment: I think better to have href for SEO and correct syntax purpose.

Comment: @ValentinPetkov an <a> tag with no href attribute is perfectly valid https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element

Answer (score 0):

Start without the href attribute or, if you want to remove it programmatically use:

```
$("#certificate_enrol_link").removeAttr("href")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be:

```
$('#certificate_enrol_link').click(function(event) {
  if ('#' == $(this).attr('href')) {
    alert("Please select an option!");
    return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/punkhaa/xwktk9ec/)

i have used `preventDefault()` to `disable` the link

```
$('.link_dis').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
})

  <a id="certificate_enrol_link" class="link_dis"href="#" class="orange_btn">ENROL NOW</a
```