# disable inputs from a form using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

i need to disable all inputs from a form when a php condition is true. i tried something like that but it does not work. if someone can help me :)

```
<?php if(1==1){?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#formEtape1').find('input, textarea, button, select').prop('disabled',true);
        });
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Why not add disabled to the form fields since you are on the server anyway?

Comment: Try `attr` in place of `prop`

Comment: Please re-direct to this link for a full explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414365/disable-enable-an-input-with-jquery

Comment: but `$('#formEtape1').find('input, textarea, button, select').attr('disabled','disabled');` still not working