# How to disable an input with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do it like this which has worked for me before but is not working for me now.

```
$("input").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Can anyone tel me why it is not working while it has worked for me in previous projects.

Comment: This is actually a lot simpler with vanilla JavaScript. `element.disabled = true`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable/enable an input with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414365/disable-enable-an-input-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is old style was applicable for Jquery 1.5 and below. For version 1.6 and above you need to write this

```
$("input").prop('disabled', true);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You must have upgraded to newer version of jQuery which is greater than 1.5.
For jQuery greater than 1.5, `attr` will not work but need to use `prop` as shown below.

```
$("input").prop('disabled','disabled');
```

Comment: Set the property to true (or false), not to a string.