# Jquery add and remove disable attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having some checkboxes and text inputs. The Text inputs are disabled when the pages loads. If a checkbox is checked, the corresponding input should be fillable. Here's my current code

For some reason I can't seem to get it right, I'm pretty new to JS and Jquery.
When I click the checkboxes, nothing happens, and when I load the page I get 6 times the text "false"

```
    var c1 = $('#check1');
    var c2 = $('#check2');
    var c3 = $('#check3');

    var f1 = $('#field1');
    var f2 = $('#field2');
    var f3 = $('#field3');

    $(function() {
        enable_cb(c1, f1);
        enable_cb(c2, f2);
        enable_cb(c3, f3);

        c1.click(enable_cb(c1, f1));
        c2.click(enable_cb(c2, f2));
        c3.click(enable_cb(c3, f3));
    });


    function enable_cb(checkbox, field) {
        if (checkbox.checked) {
            console.log('if');
            field.removeAttr("disabled");
        } else {
            console.log('else');
            field.attr("disabled", true);
        }
    }
```

Here's a piece of html, the other parts look the same as this one:

```
<div class="form-group" >
    <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect customcheckbox" for="check1">
        {{ Form::checkbox('check', 1, null, ['class' => 'mdl-checkbox__input', 'id' => 'check1']) }}
        <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">test</span>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group" >
    <label for="field1">test<br></label>
    <select id="field1" name="field1" disabled class="searchselect searchselectstyle">
    </select>
    @if ($errors->has('field1'))
        <span class="help-block">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first('field1') }}</strong>
        </span>
    @endif
</div>
```

Comment: Post your html please

Comment: Check [this Question at stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414365/disable-enable-an-input-with-jquery) to better understand how to deal with enabling and disabling inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several issues.

- You should use the `change` event when dealing with checkboxes so that people who navigate with the keyboard can use them.
- You should provide an anonymous function to the event handler. You current code is immediately executing the `enable_cb()` function and then ignoring any further events.
- The `checkbox` parameter passed to the function is a jQuery object which has no `checked` property. You should use `is(':checked')` instead.
- You should use `prop()` over `attr()` and `removeAttr()` where possible.

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    enable_cb(c1, f1);
    enable_cb(c2, f2);
    enable_cb(c3, f3);

    c1.change(function() {
        enable_cb(c1, f1)
    });
    c2.change(function() {
        enable_cb(c2, f2)
    });
    c3.change(function() {
        enable_cb(c3, f3)
    });
});

function enable_cb(checkbox, field) {
    if (checkbox.is(':checked')) {
        console.log('if');
        field.prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
        console.log('else');
        field.prop("disabled", true);
    }
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/14ks7at8/)

That said, you should really look to DRY up your code to reduce repetition. Exactly how you do this depends on your HTML structure, but here's an example.

```
<div class="checkbox-group">
    <input type="checkbox" id="check" />
    <input type="text" id="subcomplex"/>
</div>
<div class="checkbox-group">
    <input type="checkbox" id="yearlymanagermaintainancedayscheck" />
    <input type="text" id="yearlymanagermaintainancedays" />
</div>
<div class="checkbox-group">
    <input type="checkbox" id="yearlysuppliermaintainancedayscheck" />
    <input type="text" id="yearlysuppliermaintainancedays" />
</div>
```

```js
$('.checkbox-group :checkbox').change(function() {
    $(this).siblings('input').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
}).change();
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/14ks7at8/2/)

Note how much simpler the code is for the latter version, and how the JS will require no updates or maintenance no matter how many `input` elements you add to the HTML.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's working great now. I'm very new to JS so this helped me a lot.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to toggle a property using jQuery, you can use the [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) function, which you could use to toggle the `disabled` property :

```
$(yourElement).prop('disabled',!checkbox.checked);
```

which in your case might look something like :

```
function enable_cb(checkbox, field) {
    $(field).prop('disabled',!checkbox.checked);
}
```