# How to enable and disable input form with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, datepicker

In short this is the case, I want to create a form that consists of two parts with identity `section_1` and `section_2`. In `section_1` label B is input your birth date that will determine the input of age. Original condition send button is disabled.

The first question is how to input required in the contents can not be empty to make the send button is enabled and if the value of the label and more than 17 years, the condition `section_2` should be disabled?
This stage I use this code:

```
<form action="my_url" method="post">
<div id="section_1" style="padding:1em">
<p>
<label>A : </label><input id="entry_1" type="text" required="" />
</p>
<p>
<label>B : </label><input id="entry_2" type="text" required="" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" />
                    <input id="age" type="hidden" name="age"/>
</p>
<p>
<label>C : </label><input id="entry_3" type="text" />
</p>
</div>

<div id="section_2" style="padding:1em">
<p>
<label>D : </label><input id="entry_4" type="text" required="" />
</p>
<p>
<label>E : </label><input id="entry_5" type="text" required="" />
</p>
<p>
<label>F : </label><input id="entry_6" type="text" required="" />
</p>
</div>

<div>
<input id="send" type="submit" value="submit" />
</div>
</form>

<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#entry_2').keyup(function() {
            if(isDate($('#entry_2').val())) {
                var age = calculateAge(parseDate($('#entry_2').val()), new Date());
                $("#age").val(age);
            } else {
                $("#age").val('');
            }
        });
        $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
        $('input[required]').keyup(function() {
            if($(this).val() != '') {
                $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
            }
            if($("#age").val() > 17) {
                $('#section_2').addClass('disabled');
                $('#section_2 input').prop({
                    'disabled': true,
                    'title': 'Skip this step'
                });
            } else if($("#age").val() < 17) {
                $('#section_2').removeClass('disabled');
                $('#section_2 input').prop({
                    'disabled': false,
                    'title': 'Must be filled'
                });
            }
        });
    });

    //convert the date string in the format of dd/mm/yyyy into a JS date object
    function parseDate(dateStr) {
        var dateParts = dateStr.split("/");
        return new Date(dateParts[2], (dateParts[1] - 1), dateParts[0]);
    }

    //is valid date format
    function calculateAge(dateOfBirth, dateToCalculate) {
        var calculateYear = dateToCalculate.getFullYear();
        var calculateMonth = dateToCalculate.getMonth();
        var calculateDay = dateToCalculate.getDate();

        var birthYear = dateOfBirth.getFullYear();
        var birthMonth = dateOfBirth.getMonth();
        var birthDay = dateOfBirth.getDate();

        var age = calculateYear - birthYear;
        var ageMonth = calculateMonth - birthMonth;
        var ageDay = calculateDay - birthDay;

        if(ageMonth < 0 || (ageMonth == 0 && ageDay < 0)) {
            age = parseInt(age) - 1;
        }
        return age;
    }

    function isDate(txtDate) {
        var currVal = txtDate;
        if(currVal == '')
            return true;

        //Declare Regex
        var rxDatePattern = /^(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{4})$/;
        var dtArray = currVal.match(rxDatePattern); // is format OK?

        if(dtArray == null)
            return false;

        //Checks for dd/mm/yyyy format.
        var dtDay = dtArray[1];
        var dtMonth = dtArray[3];
        var dtYear = dtArray[5];

        if(dtMonth < 1 || dtMonth > 12)
            return false;
        else if(dtDay < 1 || dtDay > 31)
            return false;
        else if((dtMonth == 4 || dtMonth == 6 || dtMonth == 9 || dtMonth == 11) && dtDay == 31)
            return false;
        else if(dtMonth == 2) {
            var isleap = (dtYear % 4 == 0 && (dtYear % 100 != 0 || dtYear % 400 == 0));
            if(dtDay > 29 || (dtDay == 29 && !isleap))
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
</script>
```

In this step seems almost succeeded, for input your birth date manually typed.
And the second question is when I want to make the input date of birth for the better, I use `datepick.js` http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html but it fails because it can not identify the age input value input your date of birth. I add this code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.datepick.css"/> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.plugin.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.datepick.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jquery.datepick-id.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){$('#entry_2').datepick({dateFormat:'dd/mm/yyyy'})});
</script>
```

Maybe someone can give ideas for a better solution than this.

Comment: To disable inputs you use the `disabled` attribute.

Comment: @gcampbell *property: .prop, not .attr

Comment: (By the way your `<label>`s should have `for` attributes.)

Comment: @Justinas Huh? `disabled` is an HTML attribute.

Comment: @gcampbell When changing `disabled` attribute using jQuery you must use `.prop` and not `.attr`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable/enable an input with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414365/disable-enable-an-input-with-jquery)