# diasable buttons in a table with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html page with jquery that contains a table with buttons in a column as following. I need to disable all buttons with class `Crem`.

I have try the following but not working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $( ".Crem" ).prop( "disabled", true);
}

<table id="settlementsd" class="table table-striped">
<thead>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <th>&nbsp;</th>
  <th>&nbsp;</th>
  <th>&nbsp;</th>
  <th>&nbsp;</th>
  <th>&nbsp;</th>
  <th><button type="submit" id="stlmtdadd" class="Crem btn btn-sm btn-info" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> </button></th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>&nbsp;</th>
  <th>&nbsp;</th>
  <th>&nbsp;</th>
  <th>&nbsp;</th>
  <th>&nbsp;</th>
  <th><button type="submit" id="stlmtdadd" class="Crem btn btn-sm btn-info" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> </button></th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>&nbsp;</th>
  <th>&nbsp;</th>
  <th>&nbsp;</th>
  <th>&nbsp;</th>
  <th>&nbsp;</th>
  <th><button type="submit" id="stlmtdadd" class="Cadd btn btn-sm btn-info" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> </button></th>
</tr>

</tbody>
<tfoot>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: where is your jquery?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You explained what you want to do.. but you haven't explained what is the problem and where you got stuck.

Comment: What do you mean disable? `$('.Crem').prop('disabled', true);`

Comment: Just look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414365/disable-enable-an-input-with-jquery

Comment: @karacsi_maci you could improve the selector to look only for buttons

Comment: it think you need this .... $('[class^='Crem']').prop('disabled', true);

Comment: Also inside <tbody><tr></tr></tbody> you should use <td></td> not <th></th>

Comment: Check my answer please. You are missing ); at the end of your jquery function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buttons are simple to disable as disabled is a button property which is handled by the browser:

```
<button class="btn" disabled>My Button</button>
```

To disable these with a custom jQuery function, you'd simply make:

p.s You are missing brackets and semicolon at the end of function

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $(".Crem").prop('disabled',true);
  });
```

Here is a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TFTvn/1406/)

Answer (score 0):

don't use same id for single. one page must contain a single unique id.
your are repeating id="stlmtdadd".
**here is your working Demo:**   https://jsfiddle.net/aL4xLm6a/`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $( ".Crem" ).each(function(){
           $(this).prop('disabled',true);

     });
});
```