# How to make jQuery UI autocomplete dropdown ul list item selectively disabled

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drop-down-menu, jquery-ui-autocomplete, jquery-widgets

The dropdown `classes` are `ul.ui-autocomplete li.ui-menu-item` by default. I want to make the unselectable `li` not selectable for better UX. i.e. If I enter keywords "coat" in the search bar, it shows Mens Suggestions, then Jacket, then Women Suggestions, then Sweater. When I use arrow keys to select them, it skips the Suggestions part. I have tried `.attr('disabled', ture);, .prop('disabled', true);` and `user-select: none;` none of them is working. It just adds `disabled="disabled"` to the `li`, and it is still selectable. Is there a disabled property in jQuery UI I can attach it onto the li to accomplish this?

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete">
 <li class="unselectable" >Mens Suggestions</li>
 <li>Jacket</li>
 <li class="unselectable" >Women Suggestions</li>
 <li>Sweater</li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: Did you even bother to google this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable/enable an input with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414365/disable-enable-an-input-with-jquery)

Comment: @Robert, I did google, tried everything I could found on Google(I might miss something) . And, like what I said in the description, `.attr('disabled', true);` doesn't work.

Comment: additional comments: `.prop('disabled', true)` doesn't work either.

Comment: You want to follow this example: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is to set the class to `ui-autocomplete-category` as shown in the example from https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/183he51q/

**HTML**

```
<label for="search">Search: </label>
<input id="search">
```

**CSS**

```
.ui-autocomplete-category {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: .2em .4em;
  margin: .8em 0 .2em;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  $.widget("custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _create: function() {
      this._super();
      this.widget().menu("option", "items", "> :not(.ui-autocomplete-category)");
    },
    _renderMenu: function(ul, items) {
      var that = this,
        currentCategory = "";
      $.each(items, function(index, item) {
        var li;
        if (item.category != currentCategory) {
          ul.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>");
          currentCategory = item.category;
        }
        li = that._renderItemData(ul, item);
        if (item.category) {
          li.attr("aria-label", item.category + " : " + item.label);
        }
      });
    }
  });
  var data = [{
    label: "Jacket",
    category: "Mens Suggestions"
  }, {
    label: "Sweater",
    category: "Mens Suggestions"
  }, {
    label: "Jacket",
    category: "Women Suggestions"
  }, {
    label: "Sweater",
    category: "Women Suggestions"
  }];

  $("#search").catcomplete({
    delay: 0,
    source: data
  });
});
```

Comment: I found  this post as well, thought about using it. But, it completely changed the structure of my markup. Anyway, I am going to give a try. Thanks.

Comment: You did  not include any of your markup, nor did you include an example of your code or data, so there was no way to know that when addressing your question.