# jQuery `prop` method not functioning as expected

Tags: jquery

I am getting issue with jQuery `prop` method.
If I am setting value dynamically, and then disabling the input then the value is hiding. Below is my code:

```
$("#firstName").val("First Name");
$("input").prop("disabled",true);
```

and now clicking edit button and removing disabled.

```
$("input").prop("disabled",false);
```

at this point of time, my value is again visible.
Can anybody help me in understanding this and make that value visible even on disable mode?
Thanks

Comment: `disabled` doesn't make it invisible it prevent users entering values/submitted in the form

Comment: i understand that. but i m unable to see the values which i added after disabling to true

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What do you mean *unable to see*? Please create a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's impossible to answer with this information.

Comment: This does not hide the text in Chrome on windows: `$("#firstName").on("click", function() {
      $("#firstName").val("First Name");
      $("input").prop("disabled", true);
    })` - it only greys the field out but the text is still visible. Please click the `<>` button and create a snippet that shows the issue

Comment: Please see the pen . [link text](http://codepen.io/walberg/pen/JbWVxK)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iamkarthik08/e4gp3Lak/) which I made for you. The problem is with your jQuery script loading.

```
<input type="text" value="firstName" disabled="true" />
<button id="chProp">
    Change Prop
</button>

$("#chProp").on('click', function(){
   $("input").prop("disabled",false);
});
```

Hope it will solve your issue.

Comment: Please see this pen . [link text](http://codepen.io/walberg/pen/JbWVxK).

Comment: Why you have added HTML elements inside CSS column?

Comment: no its not. if you load the page, then its getting disabled, and the value is being hidden. once you click on button then its displaying. i understand its design issue, but i need to know why its happening like this

Comment: See the fiddle which I have shared with you in my answer! If it is working fine & not working in your design means there might be a problem with your page load or design CSS

Comment: Your value is visible in your Pen!. Since the color is white the value is not visible dear.  Check manually by selecting the value with mouse.

Comment: In your CSS .form-group input, .form-group textarea {} there is a property color: transparent. remove that and run

Comment: Thank you so much karthik. you are right, its because of color:transparent.Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you. Please make my answer as the right one. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

For jQuery 1.6+

To change the disabled property you should use the .prop() function.

$("input").prop('disabled', true);
$("input").prop('disabled', false);

For jQuery 1.5 and below

The .prop() function doesn't exist, but .attr() does similar:

Set the disabled attribute.

$("input").attr('disabled','disabled');
To enable again, the proper method is to use .removeAttr()

$("input").removeAttr('disabled');

For more details [Reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414365/disable-enable-an-input-with-jquery).