# Enable/disable for text-area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jQuery to enable/disable a text-area, upon clicking two radio buttons. Here is my code:

HTML

```
<form>
   <input type="radio" id="aa" name="candidates">1 <br>
   <input type="radio" id="bb" name="candidates">2<br>
</form>
<textarea rows="2" id="candidateTextArea" style="width: 100%;">adadsajsd</textarea>
```

jQuery

```
$("#aa").change(function() { 
                    console.log("change in aa"); 
            $("#candidateTextArea").attr("disabled", "true"); 
      }
); 

$("#bb").change(function() { 
                    console.log("change in bb"); 
            $("#candidateTextArea").attr("disabled", "false"); 
      }
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uu1kje5x/5/

In practice what I see is that the text-area becomes disabled, and never gets active again. Any ideas why this doesn't work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable/enable an input with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414365/disable-enable-an-input-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `false` instead of `"false"`. No need of quotes around `false`

```
$("#aa").change(function() { 
                    console.log("change in aa"); 
            $("#candidateTextArea").attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
      }
); 

$("#bb").change(function() { 
                    console.log("change in bb"); 
            $("#candidateTextArea").attr("disabled", false); 
      }
);
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/uu1kje5x/6/) is fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the attribute set the prop:

```
$("#aa").change(function() { 
                console.log("change in aa"); 
        $("#candidateTextArea").prop("disabled",true);

  }
```

);

```
$("#bb").change(function() { 
                console.log("change in bb"); 
        $("#candidateTextArea").prop("disabled",false);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

To re-enable an HTML element that has had the attribute disabled applied to it you have  to remove the attribute entirely.

You can do this using jQuery's [`.removeAttr()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) rather than setting it to false.

```
$("#bb").change(function() { 
   console.log("change in bb"); 
  $("#candidateTextArea").removeAttr("disabled"); // <------ used here
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `disabled` attribute using `attr()` and remove the disabled attribute using `removeAttr()`

```js
$("#aa").change(function() {
   $("#candidateTextArea").attr("disabled", "disabled");
});

$("#bb").change(function() {
  $("#candidateTextArea").removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="radio" id="aa" name="candidates">1
  <br>
  <input type="radio" id="bb" name="candidates">2
  <br>
</form>
<textarea rows="2" id="candidateTextArea" style="width: 100%;">adadsajsd</textarea>
```