# permanently disable the button after submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Is there any way by which we can disable/remove a button permanently after it is being clicked.
Here is the code

```
<a href="send.php?id=<?php echo $row['issue_book_id'];?>">
  <button onclick="this.disabled='disabled';" style="margin-top:5px !important;" type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span> Send Msg
  </button>
</a>
```

Comment: Yes using jquery, this question is already available on stackoverflow and maybe in hundred thousand of other websites. Should be closed

Comment: You could set a cookie and check for it's existence on each page load. If the cookie exists do not display or disable the button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable/enable an input with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414365/disable-enable-an-input-with-jquery)

Comment: Otherwise (even if similar to @RamRaider) you can store this data in Session or in database :)

Comment: Sir @Anyone_ph, how can we do that.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You cannot have a `button` inside an `a`.

Comment: `onclick="this.disabled='true';` may work... But the wrapping anchor to send.php... lol Funny.

Comment: lol you wrapped a button inside a link tag. Interesting

Answer (score 1):

Call a function onclick of `button`. Disable the button from that function.

Hope this snippet will be useful

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="updateState(this)" style="margin-top:5px;" type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span> Send Msg
  </button>
```

**JS**

```
function updateState(context){
     context.setAttribute('disabled',true)
    }
```

Beside a button inside an anchor tag is not valid html 5. Also inline styles does not need `!important` as it comes with higest specificity

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/w5fh6smx/2/)

Comment: So you just left out the `<a href...` wrapping part to give a right answer on the main topic. +1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

You may want something like this:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" onclick="this.className += ' disabled';" style="margin-top:5px !important;">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span> Send Msg
</a>
```

Notice that I've changed the button tag to an anchor tag. This is ok in Bootstrap you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged **jQuery** to this question....

You mess with 4 languages...

One is PHP on which we have no idea what you intend to do with.
I suppose you want to send an `id` to server-side...
How will it be handled? and what is the expected answer?
*(out of scope)*

But the 3 others should be managed like this:

**CSS:**

```
#mybutton{
  margin-top:5px !important;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<button id="mybutton" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" data-book-id="<?php echo $row['issue_book_id'];?>">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span> Send Msg
</button>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#mybutton").on("click",function(){
  $(this).attr('disabled',true);

  $.ajax({
    url: "send.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: "id="+$(this).data("book-id"),    // the id sent in POST.
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
      // Success message
      console.log("Ajax worked! Now What do I do with it!?!");
      console.log("Ho!... Here is the html: \n\n" + html);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown) {
      console.log("Error: "+errorThrown);
    }
  });
});
```