# Prevent click on form button while file is loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following snippet which allows a person to upload up to 3 files with a single upload button. While the file is being uploaded an animation runs in place of the upload button.

My requirement is that I need to prevent the user from clicking on any of the input field buttons while the file is getting uploaded. I do not wan't to use the hide() function for this. Is there a way in jQuery to stop the input field buttons from getting clicked on while the file is getting uploaded/the loading animation is running.
Recently started to use jQuery so still a beginner and hence would love to use a simple solution for this. Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on("click", ".UploadBtn", function(event) {
            $(".p").each(function(file) {
                if  ($(this).val()) {
                    $(".loader").show();
                    $(".spinner").show();
                    $(".UploadBtn").hide();
                }
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

My HTML code is below. The "p" class is used for `{{ form.photo1 }}`, `{{ form.photo2 }}` & `{{ form.photo3 }}` ;

```
<div class="mtl mbl">
{{ form.photo1 }}
</div>
<div class="loader">
<div class="spinner"></div>
loading</div>
<input type="submit" class="UploadBtn btn bm bco mbs mts" style="border-color:#f57c00;" value="Upload">

<div class="mtl mbl">
{{ form.photo2 }}
</div>
<div class="loader">
<div class="spinner"></div>
loading</div>
<input type="submit" class="UploadBtn btn bm bco mbs mts" style="border-color:#f57c00;" value="Upload">

<div class="mtl mbl">
{{ form.photo3 }}
</div>
<div class="loader">
<div class="spinner"></div>
loading</div>
<input type="submit" class="UploadBtn btn bm bco mbs mts" style="border-color:#f57c00;" value="Upload">
```

[image]

> When the upload button, which the red button is pointing at, is
>   clicked an animation starts to run in its place while the file is
>   getting uploaded. During this I want to prevent anyone from clicking
>   on the choose file (), the blue arrow is pointing at it.

Comment: add attr disabled

Comment: won't it also prevent the file from getting uploaded?

Comment: add attr dynamically after upload process started or after click on upload button

Answer (score 0):

Try using prop to disable upload buttons

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(document).on("click", ".UploadBtn", function(event) {
  $(".p").each(function(file) {
    if  ($(this).val()) {
      $(".loader").show();
      $(".spinner").show();
      $(".UploadBtn").prop("disabled", "true");
    }
  })
 });
});
```

Comment: I am trying to prevent the select file button from getting clicked not the upload button as the loading animation runs in its place and the upload button disappears. I just want to prevent the select file button which is part of {{ form.photo1 }}, {{ form.photo2 }} & {{ form.photo3 }}. Also once the file(s) gets uploaded the page refreshes.

Comment: Hey, I can't seem to find the code for select button in the code you posted?

Comment: For refreshing the page: You can have a callback, and based on the result of file upload you can toggle the value of `disabled` and refresh the page.

Comment: The page is getting refreshed via Django/Python hence I am not worried about that and just wanted to provide the page refreshing info to you. The select button has been added by the <input> and Django is used its logic. I have given those input forms "p" class. Also I want to prevent click on the select file button( <input>) while the loading animation is running i.e. the file  is getting uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

In **jQuery 1.6+** you can dynamically add the atrribute `attr='disabled'` or `attr='readonly'` to your input field until you confirm that your files are loaded:

```
// put this within the code that checks if the files are still loading
$(".UploadBtn").prop('disabled', true);

// within the code that checks if the files have successfully loaded, make sure to use the following
$(".UploadBtn").prop('disabled', false);
```

Also take a quick look at what [*prop*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1414366/1046690) does in this detailed answer.

Comment: I am trying to prevent the select file button from getting clicked not the upload button as the loading animation runs in its place and the upload button disappears. I just want to prevent the select file button which is part of {{ form.photo1 }}, {{ form.photo2 }} & {{ form.photo3 }}. Also once the file(s) gets uploaded the page refreshes.