# .prop("enabled", true): not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having trouble enabling a button. I have designed a small test https://jsfiddle.net/51xea2kb/ in order to test this functionality. I test whether a number is within a range and then enable or disable a button based on this number. I have checked multiple posts and nothing seems to apply.

**Javascript**

```
function enable(TVD) {
  if (TVD >= 800 - 5 && TVD <= 800 + 5) {
    $('#submitButton').prop("enabled", true);
  } else {
    $('#submitButton').prop("disabled", true);
  }
}

$('#convert-table').click(function() {
  var TVD = 800.1
  enable(TVD);
});
```

Comment: Buttons [do not have an `enabled` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLButtonElement).

Comment: Related: [Disable/enable an input with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1414365/218196)

Comment: @FelixKling I had read this one to fast prior to posting and then used enabled..... ugh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is `enabled` a thing? Try setting `disabled` to `false` instead.

Comment: Anyone who hasn't done something just as dumb is lying. ;)