# Disabled all other radio button if name and value not same

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am making one form where I need to disable all other radio button and submit button if Radio button `name` or `Id` or `class` name not same to each other.

`ID` or `name` or `class`, I am generating through dynamic way. (`name=radio_1`, `id= radio_1`).

or

if I click on Group-1 radio button then other group should be disable.

Please have a look.

```
<label class="radio-inline">
<input type="radio" name="start_<?=$value['task_id']?>" class="group_<?=$value['task_id']?>" value="start_<?=$value['task_id']?>">
<input type="radio" name="start_<?=$value['task_id']?>" class="group_<?=$value['task_id']?>" value="start_<?=$value['task_id']?>">
<input type="submit" name="start_<?=$value['task_id']?>" value="Save" class="btn sm btn-primary group_<?=$value['task_id']?>">
</label>

<label class="radio-inline">
<input type="radio" name="start_<?=$value['task_id']?>" class="group_<?=$value['task_id']?>" value="start_<?=$value['task_id']?>">
<input type="radio" name="start_<?=$value['task_id']?>" class="group_<?=$value['task_id']?>" value="start_<?=$value['task_id']?>">
<input type="submit" name="start_<?=$value['task_id']?>" value="Save" class="btn sm btn-primary group_<?=$value['task_id']?>">
</label>
```

HTML Output:

```
<label class="radio-inline">
<input type="radio" name="start_1" class="group_1" value="start_1">
<input type="radio" name="start_1" class="group_1" value="start_1">
<input type="submit" name="start_1" value="Save" class="btn sm btn-primary group_1">
</label>

<label class="radio-inline">
<input type="radio" name="start_2" class="group_2" value="start_2">
<input type="radio" name="start_2" class="group_2" value="start_2">
<input type="submit" name="start_2" value="Save" class="btn sm btn-primary group_2">
</label>
```

My Query:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input:radio").click(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    if(val != name){
      $(this).attr("disabled", true);
    }
    else{
    $(this).attr("disabled", false);
    }
});

});
```

Please guide me how can I do this.

Comment: i cant understand what you are trying to implement do want to disable the selected radio if the `id` ,`name` and `class` are not same .

Comment: I think you should set/remove 'disabled' in a different way. Is this answering your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414365/disable-enable-an-input-with-jquery ?

Comment: I want -  if I click on Group-1 radio button then other group should be disable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Attribute selector with `!=` to get all other input not having the same name inside label with specific class as in below code snippet. I have selected all inputs inside `class='radio-inline` so that it will not effect other input tags on the page.

below is the code snippet you can use. Hope this helps you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input:radio").click(function() {
    $(".radio-inline input[name!='" + $(this).val() + "']").prop('disabled', true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="radio-inline">
<input type="radio" name="start_1" class="group_1" value="start_1">
<input type="radio" name="start_1" class="group_1" value="start_1">
<input type="submit" name="start_1" value="Save" class="btn sm btn-primary group_1">
</label>

<label class="radio-inline">
<input type="radio" name="start_2" class="group_2" value="start_2">
<input type="radio" name="start_2" class="group_2" value="start_2">
<input type="submit" name="start_2" value="Save" class="btn sm btn-primary group_2">
</label>

<label class="radio-inline">
<input type="radio" name="start_3" class="group_3" value="start_3">
<input type="radio" name="start_3" class="group_3" value="start_3">
<input type="submit" name="start_3" value="Save" class="btn sm btn-primary group_3">
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input:radio").click(function() {

        var val = $(this).val();

        var class_name = $(this).attr('class');
        var name = $(this).attr('name');

        //disable radio by class name
        $('input:radio').each(function() {
            if ($(this).attr('class') != class_name) {
                $(this).attr("disabled", true);
            } else {
                $(this).attr("disabled", false);
            }
        });

        //disable button by  name
        $('input:submit').each(function() {

            if ($(this).attr('name') != name) {
                $(this).attr("disabled", true);
            } else {
                $(this).attr("disabled", false);
            }
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: disable is a property and you can't use attr for it.

Comment: You are disabling all the input radio and submit button on ready itself.

Comment: @ Makarand Patil, I  used click event for input:radio

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:radio').on('click',function(){
    $('input[name!="'+$(this).val()+'"]').attr('disabled',true);
 });
});
```

try this: https://jsfiddle.net/bch31up4/

Comment: Seriously buddy. that's a copy paste of other answer.

Comment: Thank you Makarand, but I am really a newbie to Stackoverflow community, and don't know how to copy paste yet :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).on("click", "input[type='radio']", function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  $("input[type='radio']").each(function() {
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    if (val != name) {
      $(this).attr("disabled", true);
    } else {
      $(this).attr("disabled", false);
    }
  });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/say1j61d/)