# jquery prop,removeAttr,attr not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to select an element, disable it and enable it again using this code:

```
function change(level) {
    var node = ["ultraSuperPoint", "extraSuperPoint", "superPoint", "Point"];
    if (level <= 4 && level > 0) {
         for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if (i < level) {
                $("#" + node[i]).prop("disabled", false); //not work
            } else {
                $("#" + node[i]).prop("disabled", true); //not work
            }
        }
    }
}
```

it's running correctly but this line is not working. I already tried jQuery `prop,removeAttr,attr,removeProp`-method but still not working.

this is my html

```
<select disabled class="form-control convertSinhalaIskolaPotha" name="ultraSuperPoint" id="ultraSuperPoint"  >
                                <option value="0">-N/A-</option>
                                <option value="1">MEMBER</option>
                                <option value="2">ASSOCIATE MEMBER</option>
                                <option value="3">NON MEMBER</option>
                                <option value="4">MEMBER SOCIETY</option>
                                <option value="5">SOCIETY</option>
                                <option value="6">COMPANY</option>
                            </select>
```

all select element like this,deffarent id and name only

***i know this is duplicate but i already try that solutions.

Comment: show your html please

Comment: Please provide sample html and show how you use this as per [mcve]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable/enable an input with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414365/disable-enable-an-input-with-jquery)

Comment: Your code works. If I call `change(4)`, the `<select>` becomes enabled. See [running code](https://jsfiddle.net/8abhudq2/). This indicates that `change()` is either not being called at all or with the wrong arguments.

Comment: Show your code that is calling the method. And there is no level 4 in that code, there is 0, 1, 2, 3.

Answer (score -1):

**you can use like that**

$("#test").prop("disabled", "false");

your code will be like that

```
function change(level) {
    var node = ["ultraSuperPoint", "extraSuperPoint", "superPoint", "Point"];
    if (level <= 4 && level > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if (i < level) {
                $("#" + node[i]).prop("disabled", "false"); 
            } else {
                $("#" + node[i]).prop("disabled", "true"); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you are saying the examples on http://api.jquery.com/prop/ are wrong?