# Enable input on select option id selected

Tags: jquery, forms

I need to enable input when one option from select is selected

I have this code:

```
<div class="col-4">
   <label>Stato</label>
   <select name="stato" id="stato" class="form-control">
      <option value="Registrato">Registrato</option>
      <option value="In Lavorazione">In Lavorazione</option>
      <option value="Pronto">Pronto</option>
      <option value="Consegnato">Consegnato</option>
   </select>
</div>

<div class="col-4">
   <label>Dati di consegna</label>
   <input id="data_consegna" type="text" class="form-control" name="data_consegna" placeholder="Data Consegna" />
</div>
```

I want to enable input when option "Consegnato" is selected. I try some jQuery code but doesn't seems work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use `onchange` event [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Y3pW9/1856/)

Js Code:

```
    $(function() {
 $('#data_consegna').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#stato').change(function(){
      if($(this).val() == "Consegnato") {
    $('#data_consegna').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
       $('#data_consegna').prop('disabled', true);
   }
    });
});
```

Html Code:

```
<div class="col-4">
   <label>Stato</label>
   <select name="stato" id="stato" class="form-control" onchange="toggleInput();">
      <option value="Registrato">Registrato</option>
      <option value="In Lavorazione">In Lavorazione</option>
      <option value="Pronto">Pronto</option>
      <option value="Consegnato">Consegnato</option>
   </select>
</div>

<div class="col-4">
   <label>Dati di consegna</label>
   <input id="data_consegna" type="text" class="form-control" name="data_consegna" placeholder="Data Consegna" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fist check select value on `onchange` event, then toggle enable/disable input based on value:

```
<div class="col-4">
   <label>Stato</label>
   <select name="stato" id="stato" class="form-control" onchange="toggleInput();">
      <option value="Registrato">Registrato</option>
      <option value="In Lavorazione">In Lavorazione</option>
      <option value="Pronto">Pronto</option>
      <option value="Consegnato">Consegnato</option>
   </select>
</div>

<div class="col-4">
   <label>Dati di consegna</label>
   <input id="data_consegna" type="text" class="form-control" name="data_consegna" placeholder="Data Consegna" />
</div>

<script>
function toggleInput() {
   if ($('#stato :selected').val()=="Consegnato") {
       $('#data_consegna').prop('disabled', false);
   } else {
       $('#data_consegna').prop('disabled', true);
   }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check my below snippet. In this on change of option of select box it will disable or enable input according to selected option condition.

```js
$("#stato").change(function(){
  if($(this).val() == "Consegnato") {
    $('#data_consegna').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
       $('#data_consegna').prop('disabled', true);
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-4">
   <label>Stato</label>
   <select name="stato" id="stato" class="form-control">
      <option value="Registrato">Registrato</option>
      <option value="In Lavorazione">In Lavorazione</option>
      <option value="Pronto">Pronto</option>
      <option value="Consegnato">Consegnato</option>
   </select>
</div>

<div class="col-4">
   <label>Dati di consegna</label>
   <input id="data_consegna" type="text" class="form-control" name="data_consegna" disabled placeholder="Data Consegna" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```
$('#stato').change(function(){

    var status = ( ($(this).val()) === 'Consegnato') ? false : true;

    $("#data_consegna").prop("disabled",status);

})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#stato').change(function(){
    var status = (($(this).val())==='Consegnato')?false:true;
    $("#data_consegna").prop("disabled",status);
  })
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-4">
   <label>Stato</label>
   <select name="stato" id="stato" class="form-control">
      <option value="Registrato">Registrato</option>
      <option value="In Lavorazione">In Lavorazione</option>
      <option value="Pronto">Pronto</option>
      <option value="Consegnato">Consegnato</option>
   </select>
</div>

<div class="col-4">
   <label>Dati di consegna</label>
   <input id="data_consegna" type="text" class="form-control" name="data_consegna" placeholder="Data Consegna" disabled="disabled" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#stato").change(function() {
            console.log($( "#stato" ).val());
            if($( "#stato" ).val()==="Consegnato"){
                $("#data_consegna").removeAttr('disabled');
            } else{
                $("#data_consegna").attr('disabled','disabled');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Check these resources to understand the different ways to deal with JQuery:

[Disable Enable Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414365/disable-enable-an-input-with-jquery)
[JQuery get a Selected Option](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/)