# Disable/Enable buttons if field value changes from loaded form defaults

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Quiet new to front end dev and need to have a function where if the `form` values change from either loaded defaults or placeholder values, that some buttons are `disabled/enabled` to stop user navigating away without changing the values.

So far i have been able to set the fields to `disabled` but when i change the value back, it doesn't re-enable to buttons.  Not to sure if i need to save the loaded values somewhere first or not.

```js
$('select[name="startTimeHr"]').change(function(){
    console.log("In change func");
    if ($(this).val())
    {
        console.log("Changed");
        console.log($(this).val());
        $("button[name='addButton']").attr('disabled', true);
        $("button[name='modifyButton']").attr('disabled', true);
        $("button[name='deleteButton']").attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
        console.log("Default");
        $("button[name='addButton']").removeAttr('disabled');
        $("button[name='modifyButton']").removeAttr('disabled');
        $("button[name='deleteButton']").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="toDr" name="toDr">
  <div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="startTimeHr">
                Start time
            </label>
      <div class="col-lg-1">
        <div class="input-group" style="width: 100%">
          <select id="startTimeHr" name="startTimeHr" class="form-control col-xs-12">
            <option value="startTimeHrDefault">HH
            </option>
            <option value="00">00</option>
            <option value="01">01</option>
            <option value="02">02</option>
            <option value="03">03</option>
            <option value="04">04</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
    <button class="btn btn-success split_button col-xs-12" id="pack-TEST_split_addextra2" name="addButton">
            Add Rule
        </button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
    <button class="btn btn-warning split_button col-xs-12" id="pack-TEST_split_mod2" name="modifyButton">
            Modify Rule
        </button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
    <button class="btn btn-danger split_button col-xs-12" id="pack-TEST_split_del2" name="deleteButton">
            Delete Rule
        </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: might possibly have soemthing to do with `$(this).val()` not returning a falsy value, for example if it returns `""` or `"0"`. Since I assume this is what you used as a "deselect" in your select, check that

Comment: I can't see `select[name="startTimeHr"]` in the HTML

Comment: What is `value` of the dropdown when you `change the value back`?

Comment: @Mamun Updated the `HTML`

Comment: Replace `<option value="startTimeHrDefault">HH</option>` to `<option value="">HH</option>`. This way, the value will be "falsy" and the `else` will fire.

Comment: Remove the value of first option (remove this "startTimeHrDefault"). and it should work fine.

Comment: @MoshFeu What ever i select. So on `form` load the value is 'HH' then i change it and it drops into the `IF` as expected but when i change it back to 'HH', it still drops in the `IF` and not the `ELSE`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable/enable an input with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414365/disable-enable-an-input-with-jquery)
I'm not sure which version you use but I think you're looking for `.prop('disabled', true);`/`.prop('disabled', false);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the term value back. *onchange* the condition is always true. If you mean to enable the button when the first option is selected then you can try `if (Number($(this).val()))`

```js
$('select[name="startTimeHr"]').change(function(){
    if (Number($(this).val()))
    {
        $("button[name='addButton']").attr('disabled', true);
        $("button[name='modifyButton']").attr('disabled', true);
        $("button[name='deleteButton']").attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $("button[name='addButton']").removeAttr('disabled');
        $("button[name='modifyButton']").removeAttr('disabled');
        $("button[name='deleteButton']").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="toDr" name="toDr">    
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="startTimeHr">
                Start time
            </label>
            <div class="col-lg-1">
                <div class="input-group" style="width: 100%">
                    <select id="startTimeHr" name="startTimeHr"
                        class="form-control col-xs-12">
                        <option value="startTimeHrDefault">HH
                        </option>
                        <option value="00">00</option>
                        <option value="01">01</option>
                        <option value="02">02</option>
                        <option value="03">03</option>
                        <option value="04">04</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
        <button
            class="btn btn-success split_button col-xs-12"
            id="pack-TEST_split_addextra2"
            name="addButton">
            Add Rule
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
        <button
            class="btn btn-warning split_button col-xs-12"
            id="pack-TEST_split_mod2"
            name="modifyButton">
            Modify Rule
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
        <button
            class="btn btn-danger split_button col-xs-12"
            id="pack-TEST_split_del2"
            name="deleteButton">
            Delete Rule
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove startTimeHrDefault from `value="startTimeHrDefault"` as your if condition checks if value of select option is empty.

```js
$('select[name="startTimeHr"]').change(function(){
    alert("In change func");
    if ($(this).val())
    {
        alert("Changed");
        alert($(this).val());
        $("button[name='addButton']").attr('disabled', true);
        $("button[name='modifyButton']").attr('disabled', true);
        $("button[name='deleteButton']").attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
        alert("Default");
        $("button[name='addButton']").removeAttr('disabled');
        $("button[name='modifyButton']").removeAttr('disabled');
        $("button[name='deleteButton']").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  

  <form id="toDr" name="toDr">    
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="startTimeHr">
                    Start time
                </label>
                <div class="col-lg-1">
                    <div class="input-group" style="width: 100%">
                        <select id="startTimeHr" name="startTimeHr"
                            class="form-control col-xs-12">
                            <option value="">HH
                            </option>
                            <option value="00">00</option>
                            <option value="01">01</option>
                            <option value="02">02</option>
                            <option value="03">03</option>
                            <option value="04">04</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
            <button
                class="btn btn-success split_button col-xs-12"
                id="pack-TEST_split_addextra2"
                name="addButton">
                Add Rule
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
            <button
                class="btn btn-warning split_button col-xs-12"
                id="pack-TEST_split_mod2"
                name="modifyButton">
                Modify Rule
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
            <button
                class="btn btn-danger split_button col-xs-12"
                id="pack-TEST_split_del2"
                name="deleteButton">
                Delete Rule
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: This works if i click my 'Add' button as it will always load the default value of 'HH' but this wouldn't work if i click 'Modify' as the drop down will hold a previously selected value (e.g. 02)

Comment: Hey sorry i ment you need to make value of "HH" option a empty , i have edited the answer accordingly. Please check

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the select html as (first option value should be Empty)

```html
                    <select id="startTimeHr" name="startTimeHr"
                        class="form-control col-xs-12">
                        <option value="">HH</option>
                        <option value="00">00</option>
                        <option value="01">01</option>
                        <option value="02">02</option>
                        <option value="03">03</option>
                        <option value="04">04</option>
                    </select>
```

Comment: This works if i click my 'Add' button as it will always load the default value of 'HH' but this wouldn't work if i click 'Modify' as the drop down will hold a previously selected value (e.g. 02)

Comment: So, what you expected is to 
a. disable the buttons when you change to a different value
b. enable the buttons back when you change back the value;

Am I right?
If so, you need to set a variable to store the initial value