# Jquery/JS - css is working but attr is not

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to disable an input after a condition and i dont understand why this not working. I tried to use `$("#exemplaire_50001_0").attr('disabled', true);` and `$("#exemplaire_50001_0").prop('disabled', true);` but both are changing nothing. Im using Jquery 1.5.1 so i think `.attr` must be used.

When i add
      `$("#exemplaire_50001_0").css("background-color", "red");`
to my selector so the background is changing to red.

My question is, why the `.css` working but the `.prop` or `.attr` is not ? Where is the problem come from ? Is there an other solution to disable an input with jquery ?

Code :

```
 var test = $('#num_cppap').val();
 var test2 = test.substr(0,3);
 console.log(test2);
 if(test2 == "AIP"){
     $("#exemplaire_50001_0").css("background-color", "red");
     $("#exemplaire_50001_0").attr('disabled', true);
 }
```

html ( this how i build the html ( using ZendFramework ) )  :

[image]

Nav render :

[image]

Comment: Use `.prop` for setting disabled - `.prop("disabled", true)`

Comment: Could you please try to replicate the issue in fiddle?

Comment: @tymeJV OP is using jQuery 1.5.1

Comment: jQuery 1.5.1 is *insanely* old.

Comment: yes, for me disabled mean "prevent the user to tape something"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable/enable an input with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414365/disable-enable-an-input-with-jquery)

Comment: What exactly does the HTML look like?

Comment: Post a [mcve] please. Also, do you see any errors in your console?

Comment: No i dont see any error in my console, i just see the string AIP from the console log in the js

Comment: Post the rendered HTML, not the PHP please

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414365/disable-enable-an-input-with-jquery) :

> **jQuery 1.5 and below**
>
> The .prop() function doesn't exist, but .attr() does similar:
>
> Set the disabled attribute.
>
> ```
> $("input").attr('disabled','disabled');
> ```
>
> To enable again, the proper method is to use .removeAttr()
>
> ```
> $("input").removeAttr('disabled');
> ```

```js
var text = $("#text");
var btn = $("#btn");

btn[0].onclick = function() {
 text.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="text" value="toto" />

<button id="btn">
  click me
</button>
```

Comment: I must use a click function to disable an element? Because in my code i only use a condition.

Comment: No absolutely not, you can put `text.attr('disabled', 'disabled');` wherever you want or need.

Answer (score 0):

Can you look at this please, i maked an exemple :

```js
    var id = $("#exemplaire_50001_0");
    var test = $('#num_cppap').val();
    //var test2 = test.substr(0, 3);
    //console.log(test2);
    //if(test2 == "AIP"){
    $("#exemplaire_50001_0").css("background-color", "red");
    id.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    //}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tableNiveau" class="declare">
  <table id="tableNivPrep" class="tabData" border="0" style="display:block">
    <thead>
      <tr class="entete">
        <th colspan="2" rowspan="2" class="entete">Préparation</th>
        <th colspan="2" class="entete">Déclaré</th>
        <th colspan="2" rowspan="2" class="entete">Option</th>
        <th colspan="2" rowspan="2" class="entete" style="width:20%">Offre grand compte</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="entete">
        <th class="entete">Exemplaires</th>
        <th class="entete">Paquets</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="50001" class="odd">
        <td>Edition LDQL</td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="hidden" value="" name="idPrepa_50001_0"><input type="text" value="" name="exemplaire_50001_0" id="exemplaire_50001_0" class="saisie nivPrep Edition" style="text-align: right; background-color: red;" onkeyup="calculTotauxDeclare()"
            onkeypress="return chiffres(event);"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><select name="option_preparation_50001_0" id="option_preparation_50001_0"><option value="">Choix de l'option</option><option value="81000800">LOCAL                                             </option><option value="81000801">Standard                                          </option><option value="81000802">DIRECT                                            </option><option value="81000803">DepotCTC                                          </option><option value="81000804">DepotCDIS                                         </option></select></td>
        <td
          style="text-align:center;"><input type="checkbox" name="zone_dense_50001" id="zone_dense_50001">
          </td>
      </tr>
```

Answer (score -2):

you have to correct your code like below:

from

```
$("#exemplaire_50001_0").attr('disabled', true);
```

to

```
$("#exemplaire_50001_0").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

above code is for disable and if you want to enable it you have to remove disable attribute like below code :

```
$("input").removeAttr('disabled');
```

Comment: @robinvrd no it isn't. Any non-empty value for the attribute will disable the `<input>`.

Comment: @robinvrd nobody's "trash talking" here. It's simply true that any non-empty string works for the "disabled" attribute value and it always has.