# Why the input never change the disabled attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to enable/disable an `input type="number"` but it never changes.

It starts `disabled` and when I press a `input type="radio"` I want to enable it.

```
<input type="number" class="form-control filtros_mapa_ruta" id="n_nodes_ruta" value="2" min="1" disabled>
```

I see a lot of people have this problem and they usually try with `$('input').attr("disabled", true);` but is failing too.

The jQuery function, using `.prop("disabled", true)`:

```
$("#radio_ult_pos").on('click', function() {
    if ($('#radio_ult_pos').is(':checked')) {
        $( ".filtros_mapa_ruta" ).checkboxradio( "disable" );
        $('#n_nodes_ruta').prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
$("#radio_ruta").on('click', function() {
    if ($('#radio_ruta').is(':checked')) {
        $( ".filtros_mapa_ruta" ).checkboxradio( "enable" );
        $('#n_nodes_ruta').prop("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

Snippet (the checkbox here is not working because I'm using a jQuery UI widget, but they're working well in my code):

```js
function checkboxController() {
  $("#radio_ult_pos").on('click', function() {
    if ($('#radio_ult_pos').is(':checked')) {
      $(".filtros_mapa_ruta").checkboxradio("disable");
      $('#n_nodes_ruta').prop("disabled", true);
    }
  });
  $("#radio_ruta").on('click', function() {
    if ($('#radio_ruta').is(':checked')) {
      $(".filtros_mapa_ruta").checkboxradio("enable");
      $('#n_nodes_ruta').prop("disabled", false);
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  checkboxController();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-2" id="filter_container">
  <!-- FILTROS-->
  <legend>Filtros mapa: </legend>
  <label for="radio_ult_pos">Última posición</label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio_select" class="filtros_mapa" id="radio_ult_pos" checked>
  <label for="radio_ruta">Ruta</label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio_select" class="filtros_mapa" id="radio_ruta">

  <legend id="legend_filtro_datos">Filtros datos: </legend>
  <label for="checkbox-2">Goat tracker 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="GOAT_TRACKER1" class="filtros_mapa filtros_mapa_ruta filtros_mapa_ruta_checkb optionNodeFilter" id="checkbox-2" disabled>
  <label for="checkbox-3">Goat tracker 2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="GOAT_TRACKER2" class="filtros_mapa filtros_mapa_ruta filtros_mapa_ruta_checkb optionNodeFilter" id="checkbox-3" disabled>
  <label for="checkbox-4">Goat tracker 3</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="GOAT_TRACKER3" class="filtros_mapa filtros_mapa_ruta filtros_mapa_ruta_checkb optionNodeFilter" id="checkbox-4" disabled>

  <input type="number" class="form-control filtros_mapa_ruta" id="n_nodes_ruta" value="2" min="1" disabled>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="filtrar_btn_map">Filtrar</button>
</div>
```

I tried with `$('#n_nodes_ruta').removeAttr("disabled")` but is not working too...

Why never change the attribute disabled?

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414365/disable-enable-an-input-with-jquery

Comment: Yes, that is why I'm saying that a lot of people have this problem and why I'm using `prop()` and `attr()`, but are not working

Comment: what is the vision of jquery you are using?

Comment: jquery-3.4.1.min.js

Comment: could js be a solution for you, or you want to go with jquery?

Comment: Yess, no problem :)

Comment: Check out my answer.

Comment: The jQuery function `checkboxradio` is not defined, which is causing an error in you snippet. Do you have similar errors in your real code?

Comment: With those two lines commented out, the `prop` code works fine.

Comment: yes, the problem is the `jquery UI` widget... I don't know why crashes

Answer (score 0):

In JS, you can set an event listener on the container div and if the radio buttons are clicked, you can set the `disabled` property on the input to true or false.

```
const input = document.getElementById("n_nodes_ruta");

function checkboxController() {

  document.querySelector('.col-2').addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(event.target.id === "radio_ult_pos") {
      input.disabled = true;
    }
    else if(event.target.id === "radio_ruta") {
      input.disabled = false;
    }

  })

}

$(document).ready(function() {
  checkboxController();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Heretic Monkey said the problem was the jQuery function `checkboxradio`.

Yes, it was defined, but the problem was that the class `filtros_mapa_ruta` has the `input` as well, and that made him fail.

The solution was to call the right class, only with the checkbox.

```
$(".filtros_mapa_ruta_checkb" ).checkboxradio( "disable");
```

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

you can simply use `.attr('disabled', 'disabled')` to make it disabled and `.removeAttr('disabled')` to enable it.

Comment: jQuery’s documentation recommends using `prop` for binary attributes.