# sweetalert2 enable confirm button after disabling it, programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert2

From : https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/issues/226

```
$(".swal2-confirm").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

works fine... but after a few checks, how do I programmatically enable it?

I tried `$(".swal2-confirm").attr('enabled', 'enabled');`  and that doesn't work. How do I programmatically enable it again?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable/enable an input with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414365/disable-enable-an-input-with-jquery)

Comment: And a few *thousand* more... https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery%5D+remove+disabled

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$(".swal2-confirm").removeAttr('disabled');
```